# Share CSS styles across web components

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, mozilla, web-component

I am using `mozilla - X-tabs`, web components in my application for tabbing it. Now, i need to use `bootstrap - glyphicons` in my app. But since webcomponents use shadow-DOM, bootstrap css styles are not applied inside web components?

Is there a way around it, to share a css file/style for all web components?

Answer (score 2):

You possibly want to read [CSS Scoping Model](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-scoping/#deep-combinator) by W3C.

Each polyfill library (I’m sure, e.g., Mozilla’s does) provides handlers for `/deep/`, `::content` etc selectors.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

We faced a similar scenario with font-awesome. We had a bunch of classes that are common across web components. We loaded them directly from the host and made those classes available to components using /deep/ combinator (soon going to be replaced with >>> syntax)

The polyfill (Webcomponents.js - from Polymer) used by X-tags has support for /deep/ and ::shadow (single level). You can use these selectors to target shadow DOM from outside.

Answer (score 1):

Polymer provides an element `core-style` for this, see [here](https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/docs/elements/core-style.html).

This [blog post](https://pascalprecht.github.io/2014/08/01/sharing-styles-across-web-components-with-polymer-and-core-style/) goes through how to set it up, you use the same tag to declare the common styles and to import them.

```
<core-style id="button">
  button {
    display: inline-block;
    background: #bada55;
  }
</core-style>
```

The presence of an id makes this element a producer of common styles.

Then to import the common styles inside the shadow dom of a component:

```
<core-style ref="button"></core-style>
```

The ref attribute makes this a style consumer.

So AFIK its not possible in a standard way yet with plain web components, but there's the `core-style` extension in Polymer, or the Polymer support for `::shadow` and `/deep/`selectors.

Comment: It looks like "core-style" is now deprecated. As of Polymer 1.1, this method is the way to go: https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/styling.html#style-modules

Comment: Guess what it does... it just copies the style and injects a style tag into your root. Basically the answer is, until CSS shadow-dom stuff is ironed out and shipped in all browsers, you can just copy style textContent and place it into your shadow root.

Answer (score 0):

Web components supports css stylesheet import:

```
<template id="template-for-your-component">
   your web component
   <link href='./.../share-rules.css' rel='stylesheet' />
</template>
```

You can have a global stylesheet shares between all your components without duplicate your rules.