# Best way to distribute global styles into shadow roots?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web-component, shadow-dom

[This question](https://github.com/w3c/webcomponents/issues/609) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25211111) are related.

In that second question, they recommend using `link` to link the same stylesheet from the same location, but there can also be global `<style>` elements inside the `<head>`. What's the best way to distribute those?

My first guess is that I have to copy their `textContent` into a new `<style>` element inside of the roots, but that seems like a hack.

What's the best way?

Comment: This question is either too broad, **opinion based** or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Comment: Maybe, you can ask about ways to achieve what you need, instead of asking for the best way? For example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40973471/how-to-apply-common-css-styles-to-many-shadow-roots-at-once
With given measurable constraint and question, users could provide and up-vote solutions.

Comment: Thanks, I'll do that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Share CSS styles across web components](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29181739/share-css-styles-across-web-components)