# Styling a child of a shadow root in Shadow DOM

Tags: css, web-component, shadow-dom, custom-element

I'm trying to style a child element of a shadow DOM root.
This defines a custom element called `element-el`, which have a `span` class-named 'x' with the letter x in it, which I want, for the state of the matter, to be red.

```
class El extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super();
        var shadow = this.attachShadow({mode:'open'});
        shadow.innerHTML = '<span class="x">X</span>';
    }
}
customElements.define ('element-el',El);
```

I've tried those CSS styles:

```
element-el::slotted(.x) {
  color:red;
}
element-el::host .x {
  color:red;
}
element-el:host .x {
  color:red;
}
element-el::shadow .x {
  color:red;
}
element-el /deep/ .x {
  color: red;
}
element-el::content .x {
  color:red;
}
```

The X does not become red.
I'm using Chrome 56, which is supposed to support this...

I want to style it without putting a `style` element inside the shadow DOM. 
Here is a codepen:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OpRLVG?editors=1111

**EDIT:** 
[This article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Custom_Elements#Example) suggests that **it is** possible to style shadow children from an external CSS file -- are they simply wrong?

Comment: **For Angular 4.3.0+ till now (Angular 12.x), see: [How to style child components from parent?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36528769/8740349)**

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the problem is the fact that you are trying to use the global CSS to style the shadow tree elements.

You can use the [`:host`](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/shadowdom-201/#toc-style-host) pseudo selector, however in order to do so you will have to place the style inside the shadow tree content.

Make the following changes in your javascript:

```
class El extends HTMLElement {

    constructor() {
        super();
        var shadow = this.attachShadow({mode:'open'});
        var innerHTML = '';
        innerHTML += '<style>';
        innerHTML += ':host(element-el.red) span {color: red}';
        innerHTML += ':host(element-el.green) span {color: green}';
        innerHTML += ':host(element-el.blue) span {color: blue}';
        innerHTML += '</style>';      
        innerHTML += '<span class="x">X</span>';      
        shadow.innerHTML = innerHTML;
    }

}

customElements.define ('element-el',El);
```

Check a functional example in your [`updated codepen`](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zZKOEP?editors=1111).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was relaying on this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Custom_Elements , when thinking I can style the shadow DOM children from within an external CSS (see 'CSS file' in 'Example' part) - are they simply wrong in the article?

Comment: Check the example they provide at: https://mdn.mozillademos.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Custom_Elements$samples/Example. Both CSS declarations using the pseudo-selector `::slotted` aren´t working in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to define the `x` class in the Shadow DOM:

```js
class El extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.attachShadow({mode:'open'})
            .innerHTML = `
               <style>
                  .x { color: red } 
               </style>
               <span class="x">X</span>`
    }
}
customElements.define ('element-el',El)
```

```html
<element-el></element-el>
```

*Note*: Because of Shadow DOM's style encapsulation, you'll **always need** to put a `<style>` element in the Shadow DOM, whether using Romulo's `:host` solution, a direct class declaration (see above), or an [external stylesheet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40984891/4600982).

Of course if you use an inherited CSS property (like `color`) that will aplly to all your shadow DOM content, you can just use normal CSS:

```js
class El extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super();
        var shadow = this.attachShadow({mode:'open'});
        shadow.innerHTML = '<span class="x">X</span>';
    }
}
customElements.define ('element-el',El);
```

```css
element-el {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<element-el></element-el>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was relaying on this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Custom_Elements , when thinking I can style the shadow DOM children from within an external CSS (see 'CSS file' in 'Example' part) - are they simply wrong in the article?

Comment: @YuvalA. yes they are wrong with the `::slotted` styles. They don't work because they are not at the right place (in a shadow DOM's <style> element).

Answer (score -1):

This may help someone else in a similar situation.

In my case I have:

```
<svg class="icon">
    <use xlink:href="#my-icon"></use>
</svg>
```

and to access the rendered icon in #shadow-root, I use:

```
.icon use {
  fill: #f80;
}
```

Comment: How is this relevant?