# CSS In JS vs Shadow DOM

Tags: shadow-dom, jss

Webcomponents use the shadow dom for style encapsulation . From the specifications you know that the styles inside the shadow root are locally scoped . What would be the effect on memory when you instantiate the same webcomponent multiple times ? Ex : You instantiate your custom button webcomponent 10 times .

Example

```
#Shadow-root
<style>
.outer {
  border: 2px solid brown;
  border-radius: 1em;
  background: red;
  font-size: 20pt;
  width: 12em;
  height: 7em;
  text-align: center;
}
.inner {
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  padding: 0.5em;
}
.name {
  color: black;
  background: white;
  font-family: "Marker Felt", cursive;
  font-size: 45pt;
  padding-top: 0.2em;
}
</style>
<div/>
```

I might import the style.css or place something inline like above .  There might be props to the custom element and based on the props the component behaviour keeps changing .  Now if such a component gets repeated 50 times , then I would see the inline style also getting repeated 50 times . Does browsers do any optimization between instances ?

If the style is getting duplicated then isnt the css in js a better solution than shadow dom for encapsulation ? You could really optimize the css thats used in the entire dom with a decent jss generation plugin.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Share style across web components "of the same type"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42645363/share-style-across-web-components-of-the-same-type)

Answer (score 0):

> If the style is getting duplicated then isnt the css in js a better solution than shadow dom for encapsulation ?

Wherever the CSS is placed globally or inside a Shadow DOM, it is always applied to all the DOM tree (and therefore duplicated to all the DOM elements matched).

> What would be the effect on memory when you instantiate the same webcomponent multiple times ?

So I doubt using a unique global CSS  tag will optimize anything. At least not for 50 occurences. Maybe yes with hundreds.

Also it depends on the browser implementation and thereforce will be very vendor-dependant, and may vary in time as new browser version are released.

=> I can only recommend you to test/benchmark your specific use case.

Comment: In the example i gave , the style tag content is 20 lines... which is for a relatively smaller component . But some components can carry styles of 100 to 500 lines. Ex : some ant-design input component styles.. Isnt this not bloating the dom ? I dont need to do this with unique classnames in css-in-js.

Comment: Maybe but it's not specific to custom element and shadow dom. It's the case with every html element : the CSS style is applied to every elements. In order to optimize the style rendering you'd better concentrate on CSS style good practice, that is: choose some rules that will generate a minimum of recalcultations. It's not a question of size but quality :-/

Comment: May be i have to be more specific . css in js  1 input control style is 500 lines of css . 10 input controls style = 500 lines . But with inline styling in shadow dom 1 input control =500 lines . 10 input controls = 10 * 500 = 5000 lines .  Is there no impact on the browser performance ?  Doesnt the browser need to understand 4950 lines more in case of webcomponents with shadow dom & inline styling ?

Comment: What is CPU-consuming is not to parse 5000 lines of CSS code but to recalculate badly designed complex CSS layout, with or without Shadow DOM.

Comment: I think the point here is not about good css or bad css . My question is about the technology , the overhead a technical approach is adding .

Comment: I've already answered: the overhead depends on the specific hardware, the browser-specific implementation, the developer-specific coding, the specific use case so it must be tested in real conditions. There's no general answer to such a question.