# Extending HTMLStyleElement with Custom Elements v1

Tags: stylesheet, web-component, custom-element

For years I have managed my (many) STYLE elements with the pattern:

[*simplified code for brievity*]

```
    <STYLE id="theme1" onload="myStyleManager.init(this)">
       ...
    </STYLE>
    <STYLE id="theme2" onload="myStyleManager.init(this)">
       ...
    </STYLE>
    <STYLE id="devmode" onload="myStyleManager.init(this)">
       ...
    </STYLE>
```

In `myStyleManager` I can then easy

- disable/enable STYLE definitions
- add/delete rules
- etc

**Custom Elements Objective:**

Replace `<STYLE>` with `<CARDTS-STYLE>` so I can init in the `connectedCallback`:

```
    class StyleElement extends HTMLStyleElement {
        constructor() {
            super();
        }
        connectedCallback() {
            myStyleManager.init(this);
        }
    }
    __defineElement('cardts-style', StyleElement);
```

This (ofcourse) doesn't work because I can only extend HTMLElement

0 results searching StackOverflow for [[custom element] HTMLStyleElement](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcustom-element%5D+HTMLStyleElement)

And the rest of the Web doesn't have any pointer either.

**Questions:**

1. Is it possible to extend STYLE?
2. Is it better to wrap CARDTS-STYLE around a child element STYLE?

Comment: Note that the polymer library used tu use `<style is=custom-style>` in its first release https://polymer-library.polymer-project.org/1.0/api/elements/custom-style but then switched to `<custom-style>` with a `<style>` element inside https://polymer-library.polymer-project.org/3.0/api/elements/custom-style

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to extend STYLE?

Yes

> Is it better to wrap CARDTS-STYLE around a child element STYLE?

I don't think so but it depends on what you want to achieve.

---

If you want to manage stylesheet you may consider using a new feature called [Constructable Stylesheets](https://wicg.github.io/construct-stylesheets/) that will permit to [load, define and add CSS stylesheets](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2019/02/constructable-stylesheets) to HTML document and to Shadow DOMs as well.

You can find a [running illustration in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42647968/4600982) that already works with Chrome 73 and Opera 60.

Comment: FYI Chrome 73 is scheduled for March 12th 2019