# ::slotted CSS selector for nested children in shadowDOM slot

Tags: css, css-selectors, web-component, shadow-dom, custom-element

The CSS `::slotted` selector selects children of the `<slot>` element.

However, when trying to select grandchildren like with `::slotted(*)`, `::slotted(*) *`, or `::slotted(* *)`, the selector doesn't seem to take effect.

```js
class MyElement extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    const shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'})
    shadowRoot.innerHTML = `
      <style>
        ::slotted(*) {
          display: block;
          border: solid blue 1px;
          padding: 3px;
        }
        ::slotted(*) span {
          display: block;
          border: solid red 1px;
          padding: 3px;
        }
        ::slotted(* span) {
          display: block;
          border: solid green 1px;
          padding: 3px;
        }
      </style>
      <slot></slot>
    `;
  }
}
customElements.define('my-element', MyElement);
```

```html
<my-element>
  <p>
    <span>Test</span>
  </p>
</my-element>
```

Note how the span doesn't get the border.

Is this expected behavior? I wasn't able to find concrete documentation for this.

If yes, is there a way to work around this?

Comment: This worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66424401/how-to-get-element-inside-slot-in-js

Answer (score 77, accepted):

## styling ::slotted elements in shadowDOM

[image]

**TL;DR**

- ::slotted Specs: https://drafts.csswg.org/css-scoping/#slotted-pseudo
- slotted content **remains** in ***light*** **DOM**, is **reflected** to a `<slot>` in ***shadow*** **DOM**
- `::slotted(x)` targets the lightDOM outer-Element (aka 'skin'), **NOT** the SLOT in shadowDOM
- `::slotted(x)` takes [**basic** selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors#basic_selectors)
- Inheritable styles trickle into shadowDOM
  https://lamplightdev.com/blog/2019/03/26/why-is-my-web-component-inheriting-styles/
- For the latest WHATWG discussion on SLOT and related topics, see

  - https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/6051#issuecomment-816971072
    Participants: **rniwa** (Apple) , **annvk** (Mozilla), **dominic** (Google)
  - https://github.com/WICG/webcomponents/issues/934#issuecomment-906063140

**Interesting reads:**

- [A history of the HTML <slot> element](https://component.kitchen/blog/posts/a-history-of-the-html-slot-element) by Jan Miksovsky
- [Summary of positions on contentious bits of Shadow DOM — Web Components F2F on 2015-04-24](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15rIpbH8uoiT4soB5WpLAI-geJgHf03wlgtlyUoJ_NuU/edit#gid=0)

---

## background

Yes, `::slotted()` not styling nested elements is expected behavior.

The term `slotted` is counterintuitive,
it implies element lightDOM is ***moved*** to shadowDOM

> slotted lightDOM is **NOT moved**, it remains.. hidden.. in lightDOM
> the content (IF slotted) is **reflected** to a `<slot></slot>`

Or from [Google Developer Documentation](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-components/shadowdom?hl=en#composition_slot)

> ,       .
>  '   ;          .

I use the term **reflected** instead of **render** because **render** implies you can access it **in** shadowDOM.
**You can not**, because slotted content isn't **in** shadowDOM... only **reflected** from lightDOM.

---

#### Why :slotted has limited functionality

More advanced shadowDOM styling was tried.

WebComponents version 0 (v0) had `<content>` and `::content`; but it was removed from the spec:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/content

The main takeway from the W3C standards discussions
(@hayatoito (Google team) [here](https://github.com/w3c/webcomponents/issues/331) and [here](https://github.com/w3c/webcomponents/issues/745)) is:

[image]

So in V1 we have `:slotted`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::slotted

---

#### Addition #1 : Performance if ::slotted allowed for complex selectors

From Mozilla developer Emilio:

source: https://github.com/w3c/webcomponents/issues/889

> The performance issue is that it increments the amount of subtrees in
> which every node needs to go look for rules that affect to them.
>
> Right now the logic goes like: if you're slotted, traverse your slots
> and collect rules in their shadow trees as needed. [This is the code](https://searchfox.org/mozilla-central/rev/a315a1a0f09550e23e4590a77e74f36543315da3/servo/components/style/rule_collector.rs#264)
> This is nice because the complexity of styling the element
> depends directly on the complexity of the shadow trees that you're
> building, and it only affects slotted nodes.
>
> If you want to allow combinators past slotted then every node would
> need to look at its ancestor and prev-sibling chain and look at which
> ones of them are slotted, then do that process for all their slots.
> Then, on top, you also need to change the general selector-matching
> code so that selectors that do not contain slotted selectors don't
> match if you're not in the right shadow tree.
>
> That's a cost that you pay for all elements, regardless of whether you
> use Shadow DOM or ::slotted, and is probably just not going to fly.

---

## So due to performance issues

### `:slotted( S )` got limited CSS selector functionality:

- ► it only takes simple selectors for S. --> Basically anything with a space won't work
- ► it only targets lightDOM **'skin'**. --> In other words, only the first level

```
<my-element>
  <h1>Hello World</h1> 
  <p class=foo>
    <span>....</span>
  </p>
  <p class=bar>
    <span>....</span>
  </p>
</my-element>
```

- `::slotted(h1)` and `::slotted(p)` works
- `::slotted(.foo)` works
- `::slotted(span)` (or anything deeper) will not work (not a **'skin'** element)

**Note:** `::slotted([Simple Selector])` confirms to Specificity rules,
but (being simple) does **not add weight** to lightDOM **skin** selectors, so never gets higher Specificity.
You *might* need `!important` in some (rare) use cases.

```
 <style>
  ::slotted(H1) {
    color: blue !important;
  }
 <style>
```

---

## Styling slotted content

Also see: [Applying more in depth selection to the :host CSS pseudo class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59703607/applying-more-in-depth-selection-to-the-host-css-pseudo-class/59717050#59717050)

#### #1 - style lightDOM

The `<span>` is hidden in lightDOM, any changes made there will continue to **reflect** to its *slotted* representation.

That means you can apply any styling you want **with CSS in the main DOM**
(or a parent shadowDOM container if you wrapped `<my-element>` in one)

```
 <style>
  my-element span {
    .. any CSS you want
  }
 <style>
```

#### #2 - (workaround) move lightDOM to shadowDOM

If you **move** lightDOM **to** shadowDOM with: `this.shadowRoot.append(...this.childNodes)`

you can do all styling you want in a shadowDOM `<style>` tag.

Note: You can **not** use `<slot></slot>` and `:slotted()` anymore now.
`<slot>s` only works with content **reflected** from lightDOM.

For an example where an element wraps ***itself*** in an extra shadowDOM layer,
so **no** CSS bleeds out, and `<slot>s` can be used, see:

- https://jsfiddle.net/WebComponents/5w3o2q4t/?slotmeister

#### #3 - ::part (shadow Parts)

It is a different/powerful way of styling shadowDOM content:

Apple finally implemented shadowParts in Safari 13.1, March 2020

see:

- **https://meowni.ca/posts/part-theme-explainer/**
- https://css-tricks.com/styling-in-the-shadow-dom-with-css-shadow-parts/
- https://dev.to/webpadawan/css-shadow-parts-are-coming-mi5
- https://caniuse.com/mdn-html_global_attributes_exportparts

**Note!** `::part` styles *shadowDOM*,
`<slot></slot>` content remains in *lightDOM*!

---

## references

*be aware: might contain v0 documentation!*

- https://css-tricks.com/encapsulating-style-and-structure-with-shadow-dom/
- https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-components/shadowdom?hl=en#composition_slot
- https://polymer-library.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/style-shadow-dom#style-your-elements
- https://github.com/w3c/webcomponents/issues/331
- https://github.com/w3c/webcomponents/issues/745
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSlotElement/slotchange_event
- ::part() - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::part

---

### Example: Using slots as a router

Change the slot-name on buttonclick and ***reflect***  content from lightDOM:

```html
<template id=MY-ELEMENT>
  <style>
    ::slotted([slot="Awesome"]){
      background:lightgreen
    }
  </style>
  <slot><!-- all unslotted content goes here --></slot>
  <slot id=answer name=unanswered></slot>
</template>
<style>/* style all IMGs in lightDOM */
  img { max-height: 165px;border:3px dashed green }
  img:hover{ border-color:red }
</style>
<my-element><!-- content below is: lightDOM! -->
  SLOTs are: <button>Cool</button> <button>Awesome</button> <button>Great</button>
  <span slot=unanswered>?</span>
  <div  slot=Cool>   <img src="https://i.imgur.com/VUOujQT.jpg"></div>
  <span slot=Awesome><b>SUPER!</b></span>
  <div  slot=Awesome><img src="https://i.imgur.com/y95Jq5x.jpg"></div>
  <div  slot=Great>  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/gUFZNQH.jpg"></div>
</my-element>
<script>
  customElements.define('my-element', class extends HTMLElement {
    connectedCallback() {
      this.attachShadow({mode:'open'})
          .append(document.getElementById(this.nodeName).content.cloneNode(true));
      this.onclick = (evt) => {
           const label = evt.composedPath()[0].innerText; // Cool,Awesome,Great
           this.shadowRoot.getElementById("answer").name = label;
      }
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Regarding that performance comment, no evidence was provided. We need to see numbers. There are plenty of APIs that are "slow" in the web, and they aren't all bad when they are used correctly.

Comment: @trusktr Yeah… Having a bad performance is a terrible reason to remove a feature. eg: Animating width performs terribly, but it's up to the developer to do it or not.

Comment: @FeldsLiscia So true. And in most cases, even on the slowest low-end phones, probably even on smart watches, such an animation would work fine. Animating one or two things is different than, say, animating 100 or 1000 things. Developers should have options, and know when to use them. Documentation is important here.

Comment: How does slotted help in case of nested web components I mean a wc nested inside another wc, but via slots

Comment: Not, slots slot per shadowroot

Comment: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::slotted#syntax) says this `::slotted( <compound-selector> )` What does compound selector mean here?

Comment: in layman's terms, No spaces in between