# What happens to child nodes if there is no `<slot />`, but a shadow root

Tags: javascript, web-component, custom-element

Consider this code:

```
//js
class FooBar extends HTMLElement {
  constructor(){
    super();
  }
}

customElements.define('foo-bar', FooBar);


<!-- html -->
<foo-bar>
  <h1>Test</h1>
</foo-bar>
```

This will show »Test« within the browser.

If the constructor is changed to:

```
constructor () {
  super();
  this.shadow = this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' }) 
}
```

The »Test« disappears, since there is a shadow root now.

If the constructor is furthermore changed to

```
constructor () {
  super();
  this.shadow = this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });
  this.shadow.appendChild(document.createElement('slot')); 
}
```

The »Test« appears again, since there is now a default slot for all child Nodes of `<foo-bar>`

But what happens to the child nodes if there is no `<slot />` within the shadow root. They still appear within `this.children` and its `style.display` property remains `""`. So they are within the dom, but not rendered, even thou thr css tells the opposite? What exactly happens here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The full detailed explanation is at: [::slotted CSS selector for nested children in shadowDOM slot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61626493/slotted-css-selector-for-nested-children-in-shadowdom-slot/61631668#61631668)

---

```
<foo-bar>
  <h1>Test</h1>
</foo-bar>
```

H1 is ***lightDOM***,
***"added"*** to ***shadowDOM/root <SLOT>*** the content is **reflected** to ***shadowDOM***, NOT moved!!!

**H1 always remains in lightDOM :**

- **invisible** (in the page) in ***lightDOM*** for elements **with** shadowDOM/root,
- **visible** (in the page) for Custom Elements **without** shadowDOM/root
- unless you move it explicitly with `appendChild` (or any DOM move operation)

You say: *So they are within the dom, but not rendered, even thou CSS tells the opposite?*

No, they **are** rendered, just like any normal DOM element. Just not visible any more.

You can test by including a SCRIPT tag in lightDOM.. it will ***render*** and execute!

---

In code snippets below

You reference **lightDOM** with `this.querySelector("span").innerHTML="weird";`

But referencing **shadowDOM** with `this.shadowRoot.querySelector("span").innerHTML="weird";`

Does **not** work, because the DIV (with the SPAN inside) is ***black-boxed*** in a <SLOT>

```html
<template id="MY-ELEMENT">
  <style>
    :host {
      display: inline-block;
      font-family: Arial;
    }
    ::slotted(div){
      color:blue;
    }
    ::slotted(span){
      color:gold; /* alas, you can style the 'box', not elements inside */
    }
  </style>
  <h3><slot></slot></h3>
</template>
<style>
  span {
    background:lightcoral; /* from global/host CSS, style slotted content lightDOM */
  }
</style>
<script>
  customElements.define('my-element', class extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
      super().attachShadow({mode: 'open'})  
             .append(document.getElementById(this.nodeName).content.cloneNode(true));
    }
  });
</script>
<my-element>
  <div>Hello <span>Component</span> World!</div>
</my-element>
```

#### Check the Component in F12 Dev Tools:

Chrome & Firefox:

[image]   [image]

The DIV is not in shadowDOM/root, remains **invisible** in lightDOM
all elements/styles will always **reflect** to shadowDOM/root

click 'reveal' takes you to the lightDOM

> So **to** shadowDOM, slotted content is a black-box of elements & styles;
> **reflected** from lightDOM
> that is why `::slotted` can only style the box, and not what is inside.

**Note:** edit that DIV in F12 Console, you will see changes immediately **reflect** to shadowDOM

---

## SLOTs & lightDOM are LIVE connections

By changing `<slot name=...>` you can make interactions (think Routes, Tabs, Answers) which previously needed lots more coding (remember those jQuery show/hide days?)

```html
<template id="MY-ELEMENT">
  Custom Element SLOTs are: 
  <slot name=answer></slot>
</template>
<style>
  img { /* style all IMGs in lightDOM */
    max-width: 100vw;
    max-height: 70vh;
  }
</style>
<script>
  customElements.define('my-element', class extends HTMLElement {
    connectedCallback() {
      this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'})
          .append(document.getElementById(this.nodeName).content.cloneNode(true));
      this.onclick = (evt) => {
           const answer = evt.composedPath()[0].innerText; // button label
           this.shadowRoot.querySelector('slot').name = answer;
           this.children[0].slot = answer;//include lightDOM buttons again
      }
    }
  });
</script>
<my-element>
  <span slot=answer><button>Cool</button><button><b>Awesome</b></button><button>Great</button></span>
  <div slot=Cool><img src="https://i.imgur.com/VUOujQT.jpg"></div>
  <span slot=Awesome> <h3>SUPER!</h3></span>
  <div slot=Awesome><img src="https://i.imgur.com/y95Jq5x.jpg"></div>
  <div slot=Great><img src="https://i.imgur.com/gUFZNQH.jpg"></div>
</my-element>
```

---

More SLOT related answers can be found with StackOverflow Search: [Custom Elements SLOTs](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3A%22Custom+Elements+SLOTs%22)

Comment: thanks a lot for this sophisticated answer! So `attachShadow` »switches of the light«, so contained elements in the light DOM become invisible? Is there a JS way to test if a given Element is visible for this scenario?

Comment: +1 for *switches of the light*, I am going to use that one! You can monitor SLOT Change Events... tada.. with the ``slotchange`` event: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSlotElement/slotchange_event. If you type: WCSLOT in the StackOverflow searchbox, you get all my SLOT answers

Comment: He he, that's good to know as well! But if I have a reference to the h1 (`document.querySelector('h1')`), is there any property telling me that this very element is not visible, because its parent has a shadowRoot without a slot, or, in other words: the h1 itself is not slotted?

Comment: AFAIK not (but I am learning every day, I'll investigate this), SLOT tag and slot/name attributes make the connection. content in lightDOM is just content in lightDOM, just junk inside the box. You could make the WebComponent check its lightDOM against content in SLOTs.

Comment: Here is a background/deep dive Github issue discussion from 2016, where the devs from Google (hayatoito) and Apple (rniwa) comment on slotchange : https://github.com/w3c/webcomponents/issues/504

Comment: Thanks again for this comprehensive answer! I guess I have to dive a bit deeper to discover the odds…

Comment: "Junk inside the box". Indeed! Everything looks fine - but you are left hunting for the reason it doesn't display. No clue provided. PITA. Include a slot if you want your web-component to display lightDOM children.