# HTML web component does not use shadow DOM style

Tags: javascript, html, web-component, custom-element

I have created a vanilla web component or HTML element. It just displays two links.

To encapsulate the thing, I use shadow DOM. However it does not seem to be encapsulated. In the DOM tree it's inside #shadow-root which is good.

**Why does the web component use the global style instead of the style I provided in the template for my web component?**

*The text is red and I expected it to be green.*

```js
class MyEl extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.shadow = this.attachShadow({ mode: "open" });
  }

  connectedCallback() {
    const template = `
      <style>
        a {
          color: green;
        }
      </style>
      <slot></slot>`;
    this.shadow.innerHTML = template;
  }
}

window.customElements.define("my-el", MyEl);
```

```css
a {
  color: red
}
```

```html
  <my-el>
    <a href="example.com">Item1</a>
    <a href="example.com">Item2</a>
  </my-el>
```

Comment: See the answers on slotted content: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=wcslot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this question already has an accepted answer, moving a slot's children to the shadowRoot isn't desirable for most use cases.

What you probably want to do is to use the `::slotted()` selector.

Just bear in mind that styles applied to a slot's children through the `::slotted()` selector only act as "default" styles and can still be overridden by using styles in light DOM.

For example, check this edited version of your snippet:

As you can see, this time `my-el` tries to apply both a color and a text-decoration style to anchor (`<a>`) children in any of it's slots.

However, in light dom, we have a `a.special` selector that overrides the color, so the `<a class="special">` will be red, not green

```js
class MyEl extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.shadow = this.attachShadow({ mode: "open" });
  }

  connectedCallback() {
    const template = `
      <style>
        ::slotted(a) {
          color: green;
          text-decoration: none;
        }
      </style>
      <slot></slot>`;
    this.shadow.innerHTML = template;
  }
}

window.customElements.define("my-el", MyEl);
```

```css
a.special {
  color: red
}
```

```html
  <my-el>
    <a href="example.com">Item1</a>
    <a class="special" href="example.com">Item2</a>
  </my-el>
```

Answer (score 1):

The full, detailed explanation is in: [::slotted CSS selector for nested children in shadowDOM slot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61626493/slotted-css-selector-for-nested-children-in-shadowdom-slot/61631668#61631668)

#### TL;DR

Your links are in lightDOM and thus styled by its DOM (in your code the document DOM)
Moving the nodes from lightDOM to shadowDOM is one "solution"; but you are not using slots then.

FYI, your code can be compacted to:

```js
class MyEl extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super().attachShadow({ mode: "open" })
           .innerHTML = `<style>a{color:green}</style><slot></slot>`;

  }
}

window.customElements.define("my-el", MyEl);
```

---

More SLOT related answers can be found with StackOverflow Search: [Custom Elements SLOTs](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3A%22Custom-Elements-SLOTs%22&so=uri&tab=newest)

Answer (score 0):

observe this line, you have to move/copy elements to shadow for example with:

```
this.shadow.innerHTML = this.innerHTML + template;
```

I've added this to demonstrate that only inline style will be applied to shadow dom elements .. so copied links in SD are using your style :)

so **red** will be `GLOBAL`, **green** will be `SHADOW` elements

[image]

```js
class MyEl extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  connectedCallback() {
    this.shadow = this.attachShadow({ mode: "open" });
    const template = `
      <style>
        a {
          color: green;
        }
      </style>
      <slot></slot>`;
    this.shadow.innerHTML = this.innerHTML + template;
  }
}

window.customElements.define("my-el", MyEl);
```

```css
a {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<my-el>
    <a href="example.com">Item1</a>
    <a href="example.com">Item2</a>
  </my-el>
```