# How do I select content of a slotted element?

Tags: html, css, shadow-dom

I have a span in my slot. And that slot contains div>ul>li. I would like to have access to the ul element.

My code:

```
<slot>
    <span>
        <div>
            <ul>
                <li>Test</li>
                <li>Test123</li>
                <li>Testabc</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </span>    
</slot>
```

I have tried something like this, but it didn't work:

```
 ::slotted(span[ul]) {
        background-color: rgba(255, 55, 255, 1);
        border: brown;
    }
```

Comment: Do read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61626493/slotted-css-selector-for-nested-children-in-shadowdom-slot/61631668#61631668

Comment: The concept of  ``<slot name=x>`` is that **its content** is replaced with content from lightDOM. In your code above you either do not need ``<slot>`` OR the whole ``<span>`` will be destroyed when content gets *slotted* into the ``<slot>``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why complicate things when you can do this -

```css
slot span ul {
  background-color: rgba(255, 55, 255, 1);
  /* border: brown; */ /* this is not valid */
  border: 1px solid brown; 
}
```

```html
<slot>
  <span>
        <div>
            <ul>
                <li>Test</li>
                <li>Test123</li>
                <li>Testabc</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </span>
</slot>
```

Comment: I am working with a shadow-dow. So, the <div> is generated automatically.

Comment: In that case also, this code should work. Did it work?

Comment: Yes. but I had to change my html-code a little bit. So, Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

To select an `ul` in a `span` in a `slot` you can just use `slot span ul { ... }`:

```css
slot span ul {
  background-color: rgba(255, 55, 255, 1);
  border: solid brown 3px;
}
```

```html
<slot>
  <span>
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li>Test</li>
        <li>Test123</li>
        <li>Testabc</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </span>
</slot>
```

Comment: Well in this case just remove the `slot` selector and use `span ul { ... }`