# When I add Shadow DOM to a custom element... where does the already declared non-shadow content (Light DOM) disappear to?

Tags: javascript, html, web-component, shadow-dom, custom-element

**TLDR:** As soon as I `define()` a **Custom Element** with *Shadow DOM*, the *Light DOM* declared within the same element disappears from the browser viewport.

Why is the *Light DOM* within the **Custom Element** no longer displaying?

---

I am learning / experimenting with `Custom Elements` and `Shadow DOM`.

I notice that if I have the following `Custom Element` *without* any `Shadow DOM`, it works:

```html
<my-company>&copy; 2020, </my-company>
```

But if I **then** add custom content to the `Custom Element` via the `Shadow Dom`...

```js
class myCompany_Element extends HTMLElement {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.root = this.attachShadow({mode: "open"});
  }

  connectedCallback() {

    this.root.textContent += 'Cyberdyne Systems';
  }
}

customElements.define('my-company', myCompany_Element);
```

```html
<my-company>&copy; 2020, </my-company>
```

the original *hard-coded* content disappears. (Even though it's **still visible** in the DOM Inspector.)

I was expecting:

```
© 2020, Cyberdyne Systems
```

What's happening here?

Does this mean it's not possible to have

- a `Custom Element` with *and* without `Shadow DOM`

and that I can *only* have either:

- a `Custom Element` without `Shadow DOM`
- a `Custom Element` with `Shadow DOM` and `slots`

Or is it possible to have a `Custom Element` with *and* without `Shadow DOM`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple solution for your use case that doesn't require `slot`s:

```js
class myCompany_Element extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.root = this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' })
    }

    connectedCallback() {
        // added line below
        this.root.textContent += this.textContent
        this.root.textContent += 'Cyberdyne Systems'
    }
}

customElements.define('my-company', myCompany_Element)
```

```html
<my-company>&copy; 2020, </my-company>
```

If you wanted, you could also zero out `this.textContent` to `''` after setting `this.root.textContent`. As far as I can tell using Chrome dev tools, doing so makes no difference to accessibility, but might be desirable from a developer experience point of view.

Comment: Ah. Brilliant.  I like this very much. Excellent work. Thank you.

Comment: Building on your solution, I note, upon further reading, I can use _custom attributes_ in my _custom element_: `<my-company corporation="Cyberdyne Systems">&copy; 2020, </my-company>` and `this.root.textContent = this.textContent + this.getAttribute('corporation')`.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell from my experimentation and further reading, this is what is happening:

By invoking `attachShadow()` in the `class` definition, we explicitly determine the element *will* become a `Shadow Host` when it is `define()`-d:

```
constructor() {
  super();
  this.root = this.attachShadow({mode: "open"});
}
```

Once the element has officially become a `Shadow Host` its *Light DOM* **will no longer display in the viewport**:

- the `Shadow Host` will not display *Light DOM* already declared in the HTML
- the `Shadow Host` will not display *Light DOM* added later, via Javascript

---

**Further Confirmation:**

> *By default, if an element has shadow DOM, **the shadow tree is rendered***
> ***instead of the element's children***
>
> **Source:** *https://polymer-library.polymer-project.org/3.0/docs/devguide/shadow-dom*

---

**Conclusion:**

The standard (and only?) approach to bringing back the element's *Light DOM* children, is to use named `<slot>`-s, in this case:

```js
class myCompany_Element extends HTMLElement {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.root = this.attachShadow({mode: "open"});
  }

  connectedCallback() {
 
    this.root.innerHTML += '<slot name="template"></slot>';
    this.root.innerHTML += 'Cyberdyne Systems';
  }
}

customElements.define('my-company', myCompany_Element);
```

```html
<my-company><span slot="template">&copy; 2020, </span></my-company>
```

Comment: I haven't tested, but I presume you can add lightDOM content later, which is then available to shadowDOM slots. Because I know changing slotnames dynamically IN lightDOM WILL show it in <slot>s. See bottom of long :slotted post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61626493/slotted-css-selector-for-nested-children-in-shadowdom-slot/61631668#61631668