# Styling an input range in shadow dom

Tags: css, google-chrome, web-component, shadow-dom

I'm trying to style an input range thumb in a shadow dom. I understand that CSS selectors can't have more than one pseudo element selector, so it seems I'm not allowed to do:

```
::slotted(input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb) {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Is there an alternative to set a style, or even an property in the input range thumb ?

Thanks,

Comment: You have to style lightDOM, not the content **reflected** in SLOTs in shadowDOM. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61626493/slotted-css-selector-for-nested-children-in-shadowdom-slot/61631668?r=SearchResults&s=1|4.1822#61631668

Comment: Thank you, Danny ! I'll take a look into that !