# How to style slotted parts from the parent downwards

Tags: css, web-component, custom-element

How can I style parts which have been slotted into a web component?

My goal is to create 'functional' components which only renders some parts based on the state that they are in (using Redux). These components are then rendered in a container.
This containers knows which kinds of children it can expect and should style the parts from the children accordingly.

An example is a feed of posts, in which all posts are the same web component which only render some parts.
Then there is a grid feed component and renders these posts in a grid.
Another chronological feed might simple render the posts underneath each other.
In both cases the post itself is not aware in the context that it is in.
I want the container component to be responsible for the layout/styling.

I kinda want the inverse of host-context.
With host-context the post component knowns in which containers it can be in and style themself accordingly. But I would like to keep my post component purely functional without any styling. (and host-context is not well supported)

This snippet shows my attempts to make the title of the post red when it is in a my-grid element. But none of my attempts work.

```js
customElements.define('my-grid', class extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super().attachShadow({
        mode: 'open'
      })
      .append(document.getElementById(this.nodeName).content.cloneNode(true));
  }
});
customElements.define('my-post', class extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super().attachShadow({
        mode: 'open'
      })
      .append(document.getElementById(this.nodeName).content.cloneNode(true));
  }
});
```

```html
<template id="MY-GRID">
  <style>
:host {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(100px, 1fr));
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(auto, 100px);
}

::slotted(my-post) {
  display: contents;
}

/* Attempts at styling the parts withing the slotted posts */
my-post h1,
 ::slotted(my-post) h1 {
  background-color: red;
}

my-post ::part(test),
 ::slotted(my-post) ::part(test) {
  background-color: red;
}

my-post::part(test),
 ::slotted(my-post)::part(test) {
  background-color: red;
}
  </style>
  <slot></slot>
</template>
<template id="MY-POST">
  <h1 part="title">Title</h1>
</template>
<my-grid>
  <my-post></my-post>
  <my-post></my-post>
  <my-post></my-post>
  <my-post></my-post>
  <my-post></my-post>
</my-grid>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You had multiple issues

- Typos: You are mixing `title` and `test` for your `::part(x)` references
- [::slotted is a very simple selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61626493/slotted-css-selector-for-nested-children-in-shadowdom-slot/61631668#61631668), so you can discard all those tries
- (per above link) Slotted content remains in lightDOM; so your elements in lightDOM:

```
<my-grid>
  <my-post></my-post>
  <my-post></my-post>
  <my-post></my-post>
  <my-post></my-post>
  <my-post></my-post>
</my-grid>
```

**must be styled from its container**.... in this case the main document DOM

So all **global** style required is:

```
  my-post::part(title) {
    background: red;
  }
```

You can **not** do this in `<my-grid>` because `<my-post>` is **not** ***inside*** `<my-grid>` **lightDOM**
`<my-grid>` can not style its ***slotted*** content (only the 'outer' skin with `::slotted`)

I added extra styling, slots and a nested `<my-post>` element to make things clear

```html
<script>
  class GridElements extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() { super().attachShadow({mode: 'open'})
      .append(document.getElementById(this.nodeName).content.cloneNode(true)) }}
  customElements.define('my-grid', class extends GridElements {});
  customElements.define('my-post', class extends GridElements {});
</script>
<template id="MY-GRID">
  <style>
    :host{display:grid;grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(100px, 1fr)) }
    ::slotted(my-post) { background: green }
  </style>
  <slot></slot>
</template>
<style id="GLOBAL_STYLE!!!">
  body { font: 14px Arial; color: blue }
  my-post::part(title) { background: red }
  my-grid > my-post::part(title) { color: gold }
  my-post > my-post::part(title) { background:lightcoral }
</style>
<template id="MY-POST">
  <h1 part="title"><slot name="title">[Title]</slot></h1>
  <slot>[post body]</slot>
</template>
<my-grid>
  <my-post><span slot="title">One</span></my-post>
  <my-post>Two</my-post>
  <my-post></my-post>
  <my-post>
    <my-post><span slot="title">SUB</span></my-post>
  </my-post>
</my-grid>
```

#### ::part Styling declared from `my-grid`

I added a `my-post` to the `my-grid` lightDOM:

See: **https://jsfiddle.net/WebComponents/75xgt3y2/**

So if you still want to declare the content in the main DOM, but style from `my-grid`, you have to move elements **from** the main DOM **to** `my-grid` lightDOM:

```
connectedCallback(){
  this.shadowRoot.append(...this.children);
}
```

#### Update #1

Also see **exportparts** for crossing **multiple** shadowDOM boundaries:

- **https://meowni.ca/posts/part-theme-explainer/**
- https://caniuse.com/mdn-html_global_attributes_exportparts
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/exportparts (jan 2021 - no documentation page yet)

Comment: Although moving the elements into my-grid effectively achieves what I was after. Now that I realize that the slotted elements are actually reflected and not actually part of the shadowDom it feels kinda wrong. I think it would be better for my to rethink my web-components so the grid layout happens from the lightDom instead of creating elements solely for the purpose of layout.

Comment: yes, it all depends on the use-case. You could also let the user define a ``<style>`` with shadowPart definitions as a child element of ``my-grid`` in the main DOM. ``my-grid`` then **moves** this ``<style>`` element to its ligthDOM on connect. That would be an onload config. If you want it dynamic you must not move but copy it, watch for changes with the MutationObserver API, and with a ``onload="this.disabled=true"`` so those styles don't affect the main DOM. -- zoveel mogelijkheden...

Comment: And one big thought: **Do I really really need shadowDOM?** Too many blogs show the use of shadowDOM where it is not required. Web Components are 3 distinct technologies: Templates - shadowDOM - Custom Elements; all 3 can be used **without** the other.

Comment: No I don't actually need shadowDOM for most of my components, I am mostly using them to organize my application. I never thought to ask if the component library I'm using (lit-element) supports rendering to lightDOM. It is like you say, most blogs describe templates+shadowDOM+custom elements as a single solution. lit-element does support rendering to lightDOM. So for this problem, rendering to lightDOM while still using custom-elements feels like the best way forward. Dank je wel!