# Prioritizing slotted styling over global styling

Tags: css, web-component

Let's say I have an app where paragraphs are red by default, but I want to use a custom element (let's call it `<blue-stuff>`) to style certain paragraphs as blue and bold. In the snippet below, I attempt to do this with a web component and shadow dom below, relying on the `::slotted` pseudo-element:

```js
customElements.define('blue-stuff', class extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super()
      .attachShadow({ mode: 'open' })
      .appendChild(document.importNode(document.getElementById('blue-template').content, true))
  }
})
```

```css
p {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<template id="blue-template">
  <style>
    .blue ::slotted(p) {
      color: blue;
      font-weight: bold;
    }
  </style>
  
  <div class="blue">
    <slot></slot>
  </div>
</template>

<p>Hello I am red!</p>
<blue-stuff>
  <p>Hello, I am supposed to be blue and bold!</p>
</blue-stuff>
```

What surprises me is the paragraph that's supposed to be blue is in fact red, meaning it's prioritizing the simple `p` selector over the `.blue ::slotted(p)` selector. Normally, specificity would solve this problem but it appears in this case, styling in the "light" dom gets preferred over the shadow dom.

**The question**: In my example, is it possible for the paragraph in `<blue-stuff>` to be styled as blue without the use of `!important`?

I've thought of so far:

- Give each paragraph not in the component a class, call it `paragraph`, and select that instead. A bit hard-handed, and not something I'd like to do, as I'm parsing these paragraphs from markdown.
- Apply the red color to whatever *wraps* the paragraphs, so the `p` itself no longer has the rule. While this works for inherited properties like color, it doesn't work for properties like margin.
- Apply the styling in the light DOM, by selecting `blue-stuff p { ... }`. It works, but now it feels like the component is not self-sufficient.

I've worked on this in Firefox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are falling in the `<slot>` trap

For long answer see: [::slotted CSS selector for nested children in shadowDOM slot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61626493/slotted-css-selector-for-nested-children-in-shadowdom-slot/61631668#61631668)

- a slotted element is **reflected in shadowDOM**, it is **NOT MOVED** to a shadowDOM `<slot>`
- slotted content is styled from the container the (hidden) **lightDOM** element is defined in
  In your case that is the main DOM

```js
customElements.define('blue-stuff', class extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super()
      .attachShadow({mode: 'open'})
      .append(
              document.getElementById(this.nodeName)
                      .content
                      .cloneNode(true)
             );
    this.onclick = () => BLUE.disabled = !BLUE.disabled;
  }
})
```

```css
p {
  color: red;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: Arial;
}
span {
  background:gold;
}
```

```html
<template id="BLUE-STUFF">
  <style>
   ::slotted(p) {
      color      : blue;  /* not applied because inheritable color:red */
      font-weight: bold;  /* applied, no inherited setting */
      cursor: pointer;    /* applied, no inherited setting */
      font-family: Georgia !important; /* be a crap Designer, force it */
    }
    ::slotted(span){
        background:black !important; 
        /* won't work, ::slotted can only style lightDOM 'skin' (p) */
    }
  </style>
  <slot></slot>
</template>
<style id=BLUE onload="this.disabled=true">/* click to toggle stylesheet */
  blue-stuff p{
    color:blue;  
    font-weight: normal;
    font-family: Arial !important; /* not applied, fire that 'designer'! */
  }
</style>
<blue-stuff>
  <p>I <span>should</span> be styled by my container DOM [click me]</p>
</blue-stuff>
```

- `::slotted()` does **not** do anything to Specificity
- Font related CSS are [inheritable styles](https://lamplightdev.com/blog/2019/03/26/why-is-my-web-component-inheriting-styles/), trickling down into shadowDOM,
  that is why the `font-size` becomes 20px
  most CSS does **not** trickle down into shadowDOM, but **CSS-properties** do
- font-weight is applied because there was no font-weight defined yet
- Only way to **force** your blue in is with `!important` inside the ::slotted selector,
  see `font-family`
- **but you should style from the main DOM:**

```
blue-stuff p {
  color:blue
}
```