# Is there a way to add <slot>-like elements to a <template> without using Shadow DOM?

Tags: javascript, html, web-component, shadow-dom

Trying to adhere to the DRY principal, I wanted to create a custom component based on a `<template>`. The code looked something like this (please forgive the corner-cutting as I'm typing this on a phone after an all-nighter):

```
// base.html

<template id="player">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
      <slot name="user-username"></slot>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

// app.js

class PlayerCard extends HTMLElement {  
  constructor(){
    super();
    let tmpl = querySelector...;
    this.appendChild(tmpl.content.cloneNode();
  }
}

define('player-card', PlayerCard);

// index.html

{% for user in users %}
  <player-card>
    <div slot="user-username">{{ user }}</div>
  </player-card>
{% end for %}
```

But after smashed dreams and long hours of research, I learned that slots can only be used in Shadow DOMs. The problem with using SDOM is that the internal styling is protected and can't be directly influenced by the external CSS.

This means that, at one hand, i can't inject the data to the template instance, nor can I use Shadow DOM without having to reimplement Bootstrap.

And I'm stuck. To my brain, there must be a way to make this work but my brain is unable to find it — either because it's too complex, or it's too trivial and easy.

Any suggestions please?

Comment: One of the more often used practices is to get data from the HTML document and place them into <slot>s. Look for some tutorials of web components on the Net.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, `<SLOT>s` can only be used inside shadowDOM

But you can do a lot more with styling slots.

For long answer see: [::slotted CSS selector for nested children in shadowDOM slot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61626493/slotted-css-selector-for-nested-children-in-shadowdom-slot/61631668#61631668)

```js
customElements.define('player-card', class extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
      let template = (id) => document.getElementById(id).content.cloneNode(true);
      super()
         .attachShadow({mode: 'open'})
         .append(template(this.nodeName));
      this.onclick = (evt) => this.style.color='blue';
    }
});
```

```css
/* GLOBAL CSS */
player-card { /* inheritable styles trickle down into shadowDOM */
  font: 20px Arial;
  color: green;
}
[slot="username"] { /* lightDOM styles are REFLECTED to SLOTs */
  width: 200px;
  border: 2px solid green;
}
```

```html
<template id="PLAYER-CARD">
  <style shadowDOM-CSS > 
    div { /* styles do not style content in SLOTs */
      padding: 1em;
      background:gold;
    }
    ::slotted(*) { /* slotted can only style the lightDOM 'skin' */
      background: lightgreen;
    }
  </style>
  <div>
    <slot name="username"></slot>
  </div>
</template>

<player-card>
    <!-- lightDOM, hidden when shadowDOM is used, then REFLECTED to SLOT -->
    <div slot="username">Ahmed</div>
</player-card>

<player-card>
    <!-- lightDOM, hidden when shadowDOM is used, then REFLECTED to SLOT -->
    <div slot="username">Danny</div>
</player-card>
```

Answer (score 0):

Danny is right, but it's also worth mentioning **external stylesheets can be imported by a Web Component** using 100% vanilla code. That stylesheet's rules become accessible to your component and for the keen developer you'll be happy to know the browser will get it from its cache rather than making another request (assuming it was previously downloaded). Like this:

```
  <!-- Component's template -->
  <template>
    <p>I'm salmon colored!</p>
    <button ord="primary">Primary button styles come from the imported stylesheet</button>
    <div class="fnt-bold">Bold class also comes from the imported stylesheet</div>

    <!-- Component's styles -->
    <style>
      /*  Importing global stylesheets will penetrate shadow DOM. Browsers use cached file if already downloaded. */
      @import "https://unpkg.com/m-@2.1.0/dist/m-min.css";

      /* :host selects the custom element, i.e. <x-counter>, not the template. */
      :host { display: block }

      /* Anything else is scoped to this template. */
      p { color: lightsalmon }
    </style>
  </template>
```

Full example: https://github.com/jfbrennan/single-file-web-component/blob/master/x-counter.html#L15

I don't remember where I learned about importing, but if I can find the resource I'll update my answer.