# Applying selection style to slotted elements?

Tags: css, css-selectors, web-component, pseudo-element

I'm trying to apply `::selection` style on slotted elements within a web component.

Here is a small code to illustrates the issue:

```
window.customElements.define('x-widget', class extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});

        const template = document.createElement('template');
        template.innerHTML = `
            <div>TEMPLATE</div>
            <div><slot></slot></div>
        `;

        const style = document.createElement('style');
        style.textContent = `
            :host {
                display: content;
                contain: content;
                color: red;
            }
    
            :host::selection, ::selection {
                background: red;
                color: white;
            }
    
            ::slotted(::selection) {
                background: red;
                color: white;
            }
        `;

        this.shadowRoot.appendChild(style);
        this.shadowRoot.appendChild(template.content.cloneNode(true));
    }
});
```

```html
<x-widget>CONTENT1</x-widget>
<x-widget><div>CONTENT2</div></x-widget>
```

Here is a demo: https://jsfiddle.net/ov4xmqsr/

The selection style is applied to all texts excepts `<div>CONTENT2</div>`. Is there a way to use pseudo-element selectors within the component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, because **slotted** content is NOT moved to shadowDOM, it remains in ligthDOM.

You style slotted content in ligthDOM (in this case the main DOM)

For very detailed answer see: [::slotted CSS selector for nested children in shadowDOM slot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61626493/slotted-css-selector-for-nested-children-in-shadowdom-slot/61631668#61631668)

I added extra CSS to show:

- Using variables (that penetrate shadowDOM) to declare a colors ones
- Using a `#selectable` DIV wrapper selects both custom elements
  See for yourself what the `x-widget ::selection` **selector** would do

```html
Select all text:
<div id=selectable>
  <x-widget>CONTENT1</x-widget>
  <x-widget><div>CONTENT2</div></x-widget>
</div>
<style>
  body {
    --selectionBackground: green; --selectionColor: white;
    font-size: 2em;
  }
  #selectable ::selection {
    background: var(--selectionBackground); color: var(--selectionColor);
    font-weight: bold;
  }
</style>
<script>
  window.customElements.define('x-widget', class extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
      const template = document.createElement('template');
      template.innerHTML = `<div>TEMPLATE</div><div><slot></slot></div>`;
      const style = document.createElement('style');
      style.textContent = `
            ::selection { /* colors only template text, not slot content */
                background: var(--selectionBackground);
                color: var(--selectionColor);
            }
            ::slotted(*) {  /* selectors select HTMLElements! */
                color: red; /* CONTENT1 is TEXT, NOT an HTMLElement! */
            }`;
      super().attachShadow({mode: 'open'})
             .append(style, template.content.cloneNode(true));
    }});
</script>
```