# Javascript Query All Selectors and do something

Tags: javascript

Goal:
Apply action to each checked element if checked, vs just the one element.

I am setting up multiple buttons (custom components) that when clicked, the border changes for the

tag within . When clicked again, the border resets.

I have 'checked' properly displaying when I click on the flash-card-check-mark (elm), however my code is only selecting the first item and ignoring the rest.

Can you point me in the right direction as to how I would go about making sure that -- any -- of the buttons being clicked will have this action applied?

(new to javascript and appreciate your insight)

Note: This is for code example (doesn't run without the component checked but shows the markup I'm using -- I would share a link but this is running locally)

```js
document.querySelector('flash-card-check-mark').onclick = function() {

  var elem = document.querySelector('flash-card-check-mark');
  var elemContent = document.querySelector('flash-card-check-mark p');


  if (elem.getAttribute("checked") === null) {
    elemContent.style.border = "1px solid #0000";
  } else {
    elemContent.style.border = "1px solid magenta";
  }

};
```

```html
<flash-card-check-mark no-default-padding="true">
  <p align="left" size="small" class="pa-2">
    <span slot="heading">Start my marketing today</span>
  </p>
</flash-card-check-mark>
<flash-card-check-mark no-default-padding="true">
  <p align="left" size="small" class="pa-2">
    <span slot="heading">Create automated customer journeys</span>
  </p>
</flash-card-check-mark>
```

Comment: So `flash-card-check-mark` is a properly registered custom element that makes use of shadow DOM and slots?

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

- Apply the click handler to all elements with `querySelectorAll`
- Use Event Delegation to apply a handler to the document, and then only pick clicks that were on "interesting elements".

### Apply to all elements

Use [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll):

```js
for(const elem of document.querySelectorAll('flash-card-check-mark')) {
  // better to use `element.addEventListener('click', (e) => 
  element.onclick = function(e) {

  // the element is available in the listener
  var elem = e.target; 
  var elemContent = elem.querySelector('p'); // you can querySelector an element


  if (elem.getAttribute("checked") === null) {
    elemContent.style.border = "1px solid #0000";
  } else {
    elemContent.style.border = "1px solid magenta";
  }

};
```

#### Use Event Delegation

You add a listener to the document instead and then filter the element out using `e.target`:

```js
document.addEventListener('click', e => { // can also onclick
  // filter only elements you care about
  if (!e.target.matches('flash-card-check-mark')) return;  
  var elem = e.target;
  var elemContent = e.querySelector('p'); // query selector nests


  if (elem.getAttribute("checked") === null) {
    elemContent.style.border = "1px solid #0000";
  } else {
    elemContent.style.border = "1px solid magenta";
  }

};
```

---

Notes

You can improve the code style itself with the following advice:

- Use `let/const` instead of `var` statements as they have much less confusing scoping rules.
- Use arrow functions (`() => {}`) since they are shorter and have a more obvious `this` value.
- Use `addEventListener('click',`  to add event listeners instead of setting handlers with `onclick`. It has less confusing scoping rules *and* it means you don't have conflicts with other people setting handlers on the element.
- Use [properties instead of attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6003819/what-is-the-difference-between-properties-and-attributes-in-html). So `elem.checked` and not `elem.getAttribute('checked') === 'checked')`.

Answer (score 0):

> If you want to select multiple element, Use querySelectorAll.
> Query Selector all Returns a nodeList.
> On that node list you can use forEach Loop

```
const flashCard = document.querySelectorAll("flash-card-check-mark");
const elemContent = document.querySelector("p");
function myFunction() {
  if (elemContent.getAttribute("checked") === null) {
    elemContent.style.border = "1px solid #0000";
  } else {
    elemContent.style.border = "1px solid magenta";
  }
}

flashCard.forEach(flashcard => flashcard.addEventListener("click", myFunction));
```

Comment: What is `elem`?

Comment: It's elemContent was a mistake

Comment: This looks close to what I'm trying to do, with the exception that the 'checked' option applies to the flashCard selector. When I change the elemContent to flashCard to check the flashcard selector for a true or false result, I get a function error.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this (I've changed the colors):

```
[...document.querySelectorAll('flash-card-check-mark')].forEach(el => {
    el.onclick = () => {
    var elemContent = document.querySelector('flash-card-check-mark p');
    elemContent.style.border = el.getAttribute('checked') === null ? '1px solid red' : '1px solid green';
    };
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The result is a bit odd as the borders work correctly, but the change is only applied to the first element in the list. If I click the 2nd element, the first's border changes. The 'checked' option is applied to the elm, vs elmContent (or rather, each <flash-card-check-mark>).

Answer (score 0):

With `var elemContent = document.querySelector('flash-card-check-mark p');`

you **always** select the **first** matching element in the page

- The **click** is *behaviour* of your **Custom Element**
- **Then the Custom Element should *add and handle* the click**
- If you want to select elements inside a Custom Element,
  use `this.querySelect...` **not** `document.querySelect...`
- Since you use shadowDOM <slot> also read [::slotted CSS selector for nested children in shadowDOM slot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61626493/slotted-css-selector-for-nested-children-in-shadowdom-slot/61631668#61631668) for

```html
<flash-card-check-mark>
  <span slot="heading">Start my marketing today</span>
</flash-card-check-mark>
<flash-card-check-mark checked>
  <span slot="heading">Create automated customer journeys</span>
</flash-card-check-mark>

<script>
customElements.define("flash-card-check-mark", class extends HTMLElement {
  constructor(){
    let style = `<style>:host{display:block;cursor:pointer}</style>`;
    super()
      .attachShadow({mode:"open"})
      .innerHTML = style + `<slot name="heading"></slot>`;
    this.onclick = (evt) => this.clicked();
    this.clicked();
  }
  clicked(){
    this.toggleAttribute("checked", !this.hasAttribute("checked") );
    let color = "pink";
    if (this.hasAttribute("checked")) color = "lightgreen";
    this.style.backgroundColor = color;
  }
});
</script>
```