# How can I access the (unamed) slot content in web components

Tags: javascript, web, components, web-component, slot

How can I access the content of the unnamed slot(='I need to access this text node' in this example) inside the web component's connectedCallback with javascript?

With javascript shadowRoot only shows it only as  without any content inside. However Chrome renders it correctly as expected.

Thanks

Please note that the actual class constructor is omitted in the question for brevity.

```
 <template id="my-option-template">
         <slot></slot>
  </template>
```

.......

Using the template above

```
<my-option>I need to access this text node</my-option>
```

Comment: Could you specify more and add HTML snippets in order to have some playground for this?

Answer (score 1):

You have one or two tech behaviours to be aware of:

- Slotted content is **reflected** from *lightDOM* to *shadowDOM* `<slot>`
  It is **NOT moved**.
  So you style **lightDOM** content in **container CSS** (global CSS in example 'green' color below)
  For long answer see: [::slotted CSS selector for nested children in shadowDOM slot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61626493/slotted-css-selector-for-nested-children-in-shadowdom-slot/61631668#61631668)
- `connectedCallback` triggers on the **opening** tag `<my-element>`
  The rest of its (innerHTML) content was not parsed yet.
  Libraries help out with more callbacks that fire later..
  but why load 2 kB, and add dependencies,
  when you can write a tiny delay yourself using `setTimeout` (works as long as your lightDOM content is not huge)
- Also see this answer: [Contents of nested slots in web component are not visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73732956/contents-of-nested-slots-in-web-component-are-not-visible/73733627#73733627)

```html
<template id="MY-ELEMENT">
   <h3>Slotted content:</h3>
   <slot></slot>
   <h3>Appended content:</h3>
   <h2></h2>
</template>

<style>
   my-element    { color:red }
   my-element h2 { color:green }
</style>

<my-element>
   <h2>need to access this text node</h2>
</my-element>

<script>
   customElements.define('my-element', class extends HTMLElement {
     constructor() {
       let template = (id) => document.getElementById(id).content.cloneNode(true);
       super() // sets and returns this scope
         .attachShadow({ mode: "open" }) // sets and returns this.shadowRoot
         .append(template(this.nodeName));
     }
     connectedCallback() {
       setTimeout(() => {
         this.shadowRoot.querySelector("H2").append(this.innerHTML)
       })
     }
   });
 </script>
```

- Note how `my-element h2{ color:green }` does **not** style the `<h2>` **inside** shadowDOM
  'red' does because some styling properties cascade into shadowDOM
  https://lamplightdev.com/blog/2019/03/26/why-is-my-web-component-inheriting-styles/
- All Library 'delay' callback implementations with requestAnimationFrame, Promises etc. effectively do the same: Wait till the Event Loop is empty

  What the heck is the Event Loop?
  Philip Roberts: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use `this.shadowRoot.querySelectorAll('slot')` in `connectedCallback` which would give you an NodeList for all defined slots. Content of slots can be accessed using the `assignedNodes` method. You then have the option to apply `slotchange` event listeners to the slot elements  to be notified when slot content changes:

```html
<my-option><b>I need to access this text node</b></my-option>


<script>
customElements.define('my-option', class extends HTMLElement {

    constructor() {

        super(); // sets and returns this scope

        var shadow = this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});

        shadow.innerHTML ='<slot></slot>';
    }


    connectedCallback() {
        let slots = this.shadowRoot.querySelectorAll('slot');
        console.log(slots);

        slots[0].addEventListener('slotchange', function(e) {
            let nodes = slots[0].assignedNodes();
            console.log(nodes);
        });
    }
});
</script>
```

More info on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSlotElement