# Contents of nested slots in web component are not visible

Tags: javascript, web-component, lit

I have a web component that should accept an arbitrary element to wrap its content in. Although I can see in Chrome Dev Tools that the slots are properly assigned, nothing appears in the DOM. Has anybody seen this issue before?

### Definition

```js
class ExampleParent extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    const shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });
    shadowRoot.innerHTML = `
      <slot name="as">
        <slot name="prefix"></slot>
        <slot></slot>
      </slot>
    `;
  }
}
customElements.define('example-parent', ExampleParent);
```

### Invocation

```html
<example-parent
  style="
    min-width: 100px;
    height: 40px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    display: inline-block;
  "
>
  <button slot="as"></button>
  <div slot="prefix">Prefix slot</div>
  Default
</example-parent>
```

### Actual result

[image]

### Expected result

[image]

### Source code

https://stackblitz.com/edit/nested-slots-ahtfyf?file=index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have nested `<slot>` elements *kinda* like you can't have nested `<li>` elements.

So like with `<li>` where you add an extra `<ul>` container,
you have to add an extra Web Component which *passes on* slot content:

**update**: added `exportparts` and `part` to show how **global** CSS styles **nested** shadowDOMs JSWC

```js
class MyCoolBaseClass extends HTMLElement {
  constructor( html ) {
    let style = "<style>:host{display:inline-block;background:pink}</style>";
    super().attachShadow({mode:'open'}).innerHTML = style + html;
  }
}
customElements.define('el-one', class extends MyCoolBaseClass {
  constructor() {
    super(`<el-two exportparts="title"><slot name="ONE" slot="TWO"></slot></el-two>`);
  }
});
customElements.define('el-two', class extends MyCoolBaseClass {
  constructor() {
    super(`Hello <slot name="TWO"></slot> <b part="title">Web Components</b>`);
  }
});
```

```css
el-one { display:block; font-size:21px }
el-one::part(title){  color:green  }
```

```html
<el-one><b slot="ONE">Fantastic!</b></el-one>
<el-one><b slot="ONE">Great!</b></el-one>
```

Comment: This is great! I ended up stumbling upon something similar but your answer makes clear why it works. I ended up abandoning this approach because, while this works, styles set on the base class can no longer affect the contents stuffed inside the intermediary component.

Comment: See CSS [::part](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::part)

Comment: I added ``exportparts`` and ``part`` to the example, so show how to '_export_' nested shadowDOM content for **global CSS** styling

Answer (score 1):

I can see what you're trying to do, which is that you want the shadow DOM to contain

```
<button>
  <div>Prefix</div>
  Default
</button>
```

but unfortunately that's not possible via `<slot>` elements.

[Per the HTML spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#the-slot-element)

> A slot element represents its assigned nodes, if any, and its contents otherwise.

This means that the entire `<slot name="as">` element and its contents are replaced by the `<button slot="as">` element, and the contents of the `<slot>` are discarded.

The reason for this is that the browser has no way of knowing how to add descendants to the provided replacement, as a void element (such as `<img>`), or deeply nested structure could have been provided for the slot replacement.