# Why doesn't DOM spec recognize flattened trees?

Tags: html, shadow-dom

In outline, the DOM [spec](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#shadow-trees) defines the concept of shadow trees as follows:

- A **shadow tree** is a node tree that is distinct from the current document one (**light tree**).
- Its root (**shadow root**) is connected with the light tree node by means of **host** reference - this is not the same as the descendants/ancestor relation in terms of DOM tree.
- Moreover, the shadow tree can have **slot** nodes and they, in turn, can be connected with light tree nodes (**slottables**) through the **assigned nodes** relation (yet again it's considered distinguishable from the DOM tree structure).

I find this picture a bit involved. It seems we in effect have not two different trees (light and shadow) but all three. Actually, a user agent renders another one which named **flattened tree**. In this tree the shadow root is a child of its host and slots are ancestors of their slottables:

[image]

One may argue flattened tree is just a "virtual idea". However, it is used in CSS and event listening and probably this fact bears out its usefullness.

> Loosely, the shadow tree is treated as the shadow host’s contents
> instead of its normal light tree contents. However, some of its light
> tree children can be "pulled into" the shadow tree by assigning them
> to slots. **This causes them to be treated as children of the slot** for
> CSS purposes. (CSS [non-normative explanation](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-scoping-1/#shadow-gloss))

Are there any reasons to introduce the concepts of shadow trees and especially slot assigned nodes when the state of matter can be described with a single flattened tree where nodes are connected with well-known descendants/ancestor references instead of having the peculiar reference named "assigned nodes"? Of course, if we crave for incapsulation, API functions like `findElementById()` would remain the "shadow" subtrees of the flattened tree intact.

Comment: Are you asking why the HTML standards committee made a design decision?  You would have to ask them.

Comment: @Robert Harvey Maybe there are well-known reasons I'm not aware of

Comment: [Nodes within the shadow tree are not affected by anything applied outside the shadow tree, and vice versa. This provides a way to encapsulate implementation details, which is especially useful for custom elements and other advanced design paradigms.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Shadow_tree#content:~:text=Nodes%20within%20the%20shadow%20tree%20are,elements%20and%20other%20advanced%20design%20paradigms.)

Comment: `where nodes are connected with well-known descendants/ancestor references` -- That doesn't sound like a "shadow tree."  References implies that changes to your data structure would affect the original tree.

Comment: _"However, it [Flattened DOM] is used in CSS and event listening"_ Can you explain that further? There is only lightDOM or shadowDOM. Slotted/assigned nodes are **reflected** from lightDOM to shadowDOM. Both are explained in detail [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61626493/slotted-css-selector-for-nested-children-in-shadowdom-slot/61631668#61631668)

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR** Flattened trees are an implementation detail.

Consider this code snippet

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <style>
            my-element {
                font-style: italic;
                color: green;
            }

            p {
                color: darkorange;
            }
        </style>
        <p>Document Para</p>
        <my-element>
            <p>Light Child Para</p>
        </my-element>
    </body>
    <script>
        customElements.define('my-element', class extends HTMLElement {
            constructor() {
                super();
                this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'}).innerHTML =
                `
                    <p>Shadow Para</p>
                    <slot></slot>
                    <style>
                        :host > p {
                            color: brown;
                        }
                        slot {
                            color: blue;
                        }
                    </style>
                `;
            }
        });
        const shadowHost = document.querySelector('my-element');
        const shadowRoot = shadowHost.shadowRoot;
        const shadowPara = shadowRoot.querySelector('p');
        const slot = shadowRoot.querySelector('slot');
        const lightPara = document.querySelector('my-element > p');
        console.log(`Is Shadow Host the shadow Para's parent? ${shadowPara.parentNode === shadowHost}`);
        console.log(`Is Slot the Light Child Para's parent?${lightPara.parentNode === slot}`);
    </script>
</html>
```

Consider the styling consideration for the elements inside the Shadow DOM. Though the main document cannot style the `<p>` element directly, inherited properties (`font-style` and `color` in this case) from the Shadow Host (`<my-element>` in this case) are inherited by the Shadow tree elements. Looking at the cascade for the `<p>` element inside the shadow tree

[image]

The rule with the selector `:host > p` *treats* the `<p>` elements as a *direct descendant* of the Shadow Host (`my-element`). The operative word is *treats*. The `<p>` elements is **not a descendant** in the DOM tree. Check the output in the console due to this code in the script

```
console.log(`Is Shadow Host the shadow Para's parent? ${shadowPara.parentNode === shadowHost}`);
```

Also note that the inherited properties of `fonty-style` and `color` are considered in the cascade for `<p>`.

Same is the case with `<slot>` elements. Though the actual `<slot>` element is a direct descendent of the Shadow Root, the *slotted* elements (the `<p>Light Child</p>` in this case) is not a descendant of the Shadow Root. Look at the cascade for the slotted element.

[image]

The element picks up the [specified value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/specified_value) for `color` from the main document's style sheet but it also has the `color:blue` property in the cascade too which is coming via the style on the `<slot>` element. Again, the inherited property is *treated* as coming via the parent `<slot>` even though the `<slot>` element is **not the parent** of the light Para in the actual DOM.

```
console.log(`Is Slot the Light Child Para's parent?${lightPara.parentNode === slot}`);
```

- The flattened tree, as you've rightly mentioned, is a construct used
  in the CSS and event engine of the browser, as a representation to
  model the parent-child relationship of styles on nodes but it doesn't
  help with understanding the DOM tree relations amongst the elements.
- The slot assignment would need to be figured out inevitably as the
  elements from the Light DOM **don't migrate physically** into the
  Shadow DOM, only references to these elements are held within the
  Shadow DOM's `<slot>` elements.
- The Flattened tree is definitely a good visualization to *understand*
  the styling part but would be hardly helpful to have it as the
  replacement for existing DOM constructs like
  `HTMLSlotElement.assignedNodes()` etc.

Also, the spec duly [points out](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-scoping-1/#:%7E:text=Loosely%2C%20the%20shadow%20tree%20is%20treated%20as%20the%20shadow%20host%E2%80%99s%20contents%20instead%20of%20its%20normal%20light%20tree%20contents.%20However%2C%20some%20of%20its%20light%20tree%20children%20can%20be%20%22pulled%20into%22%20the%20shadow%20tree%20by%20assigning%20them%20to%20slots.%20This%20causes%20them%20to%20be%20treated%20as%20children%20of%20the%20slot%20for%20CSS%20purposes.) this fact by mentioning (emphasis mine)

> Loosely, the shadow tree is treated as the shadow host’s contents
> instead of its normal light tree contents. However, some of its light
> tree children can be "pulled into" the shadow tree by assigning them
> to slots. This *causes them to be treated as children of the slot* **for
> CSS purposes**.

... not for DOM purposes.