# Style nested web component where child can be same type as, but needs different styles to, parent

Tags: css, css-selectors, web-component, css-variables

I have developed a HTML web component, with a slot that uses a HTML `theme` attribute to enable spacing out the child elements (by applying a `margin` to them). I want to control the size of the spacing using a CSS custom property, `--spacing-size`, set on the HTML `style` attribute of each component instance.

```js
class VerticalLayout extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.attachShadow({mode: "open"});
  }

  connectedCallback() {
    this.shadowRoot.innerHTML = 
      `<style>
         :host {
           display: flex;
           flex-direction: column;
         }

         :host([theme~="spacing"]) ::slotted(:not(:first-child)) {
           margin-top: var(--spacing-size);
         }
       </style>
       <slot></slot>`;
  }
}

customElements.define("vertical-layout", VerticalLayout);
```

I run into problems when I add an instance of my component into the slot of another instance, because my CSS targets slotted elements to give them the margin. Since in this case the slotted element *is* my component, with a value of `--spacing-size` meant for *its* children, it gets the margin meant for its children and not the margin needed inside the parent.

```html
<vertical-layout theme="spacing" style="--spacing-size: 2em;">
  <div>No margin on this, it is the first child</div>
  <!-- I want a 2em margin on the next element (the size  -->
  <!-- from the layout it sits within), but it gets 0.2em -->
  <!-- because --spacing-size has been redefined -->
  <vertical-layout theme="spacing" style="--spacing-size: 0.2em;">
    <div>No margin on this, it is the first child</div>
    <div>0.2em margin above this</div>
  </vertical-layout>
</vertical-layout>
```

I have created a [codepen](https://codepen.io/mikepay4/pen/abpaewB). See in the codepen I have overcome the issue by adding a second custom property, `--parent-size`. The codepen illustrates the spacing I expect on the layouts, but **is there a clever way to achieve the same behaviour with just one custom property?**

See in the codepen, an additional complication is that I am explicitly setting the `--spacing-size` to a default value in the CSS, to be applied when the theme is turned on but a size is not specified. I suppose this could make it pretty difficult to inherit whatever the value is in the parent...

I feel like the `:host-context()` selector might be the answer, but I can't quite grasp how I could use it (and, since Safari doesn't support that, I would have to look for another solution anyway).

Comment: What would be great is if I could combine the `:host`, `:has` and `::slotted` selectors to set the parent size at any component that has another slotted inside it, like so: 
```:host([theme~="spacing"]):has(::slotted([theme~="spacing"])){  --parent-spacing-size: var(--spacing-size);}```
Alas that doesn't work.

Comment: I tried, but its too much to take in and understand what it is you want. Can you make smaller snippets? And use that [ < > ] button in the editor to add SO snippets instead of a CodePen.

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman, thanks for looking, I made some edits, is it any clearer? I'm really thinking I just can't do it with one custom property, unless...maybe there is a way to wrap the elements that get added into the slots? I also wonder is it possible for JS running inside the connectedCallback to look into any parent instance (so past the shadow root) and generate the --parent-size variables I added by hand into my codepen?

Comment: Perhaps you could wrap the nested `vertical-layout` with a `div`? The div will get the parent's margin.

Comment: @Auroratide I had the same idea, is there a neat way to do this from the web component? I tried to do it from the backend and one problem I ran into is that, in practice, the components have styles applied (e.g. width: 100%), so my layout looked pretty broken - I think I need some way to copy the styles onto the wrapper too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Took some time to fully understand what you want (and I could be wrong)

- You want to specify the `margin-top` for all **CHILDREN** (except the first child)
  with: `<vertical-layout childmargin="2em">`
- For **nested** `<vertical-layout>` the element should have the `margin-top` **of its PARENT container**

Problem with your: `<vertical-layout style="--spacing-size: 2em">`, is that the `2em` is set on the **`<vertical-layout>`** **itself** (and all its children)

You want it applied to **children only**

You can't do that with CSS in shadowDOM; because that doesn't style **slotted** content.
See: [::slotted CSS selector for nested children in shadowDOM slot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61626493/slotted-css-selector-for-nested-children-in-shadowdom-slot/61631668#61631668)

---

I have changed your HTML and attributes to reflect the margins you want:

(px notation for better comprehension)

```html
    0px <vertical-layout id="Level1" childmargin="15px">
    15px  <div>child1-1</div>
    15px  <div>child1-2</div>
    15px  <div>child1-3</div>
    15px  <vertical-layout id="Level2" childmargin="10px">
    0px    <div>child2-1</div>
    10px   <div>child2-2</div>
    10px   <vertical-layout id="Level3" childmargin="5px">
    5px      <div>child3-1</div>
    5px      <div>child3-2</div>
    5px      <div>child3-3</div>
           </vertical-layout>
    10px    <div>child2-3</div>
         </vertical-layout>
    15px <div>child1-4</div>
    15px <div>child1-5</div>
        </vertical-layout>
```

CSS **can not** read that `childmargin` **value**; so JS is required to apply that value **to childelements**

As you also don't want to style the **first-child**...

The code for the connectedCallback is:

```js
    connectedCallback() {
      let margin = this.getAttribute("childmargin");
      setTimeout(() => {
        let children = [...this.querySelectorAll("*:not(:first-child)")];
        children.forEach(child=>child.style.setProperty("--childmargin", margin));
      });
    }
```

Notes

- ***** is a bit brutal.. you might want to use a more specific selector if you have loads of child elements; maybe:

```
[...this.children].forEach((child,idx)=>{
  if(idx) ....
};
```

- You are looping all children; could also set the style direct here.. no need for CSS then
- The `setTimeout`is required because all child **have not been parsed yet** when the `connectedCallback` fires.

Because all your `<vertical-layout>` are in ***GLOBAL* DOM** (and get ***refelected*** to `<slot>` elements)

You style everything in ***GLOBAL* CSS**:

```css
  vertical-layout > *:not(:first-child)  {
    margin-top: var(--childmargin);
  }
```

Then all Web Component code required is:

```
customElements.define("vertical-layout", class extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super()
     .attachShadow({mode:"open"})
     .innerHTML = "<style>:host{display:flex;flex-direction:column}</style><slot></slot>";
  }
  connectedCallback() {
    let margin = this.getAttribute("childmargin");
    setTimeout(() => {
        let children = [...this.querySelectorAll("*:not(:first-child)")];
        children.forEach(child=>child.style.setProperty("--childmargin", margin));
      });
  }
});
```

[image]

```html
<vertical-layout id="Level1" childmargin="15px">
  <div>child1-1</div>
  <div>child1-2</div>
  <div>child1-3</div>
  <vertical-layout id="Level2" childmargin="10px">
    <div>child2-1</div>
    <div>child2-2</div>
    <vertical-layout id="Level3" childmargin="5px">
      <div>child3-1</div>
      <div>child3-2</div>
      <div>child3-3</div>
    </vertical-layout>
    <div>child2-3</div>
  </vertical-layout>
  <div>child1-4</div>
  <div>child1-5</div>
</vertical-layout>

<style>
  body {
    font: 12px arial;
  }
  vertical-layout > *:not(:first-child)  {
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-top: var(--childmargin);
  }
  vertical-layout::before {
    content: "<vertical-layout " attr(id) " childmargin=" attr(childmargin);
  }
  vertical-layout > vertical-layout {
    background: lightblue;
    border-top: 4px dashed red;
  }
  vertical-layout > vertical-layout > vertical-layout {
    background: lightcoral;
  }
</style>

<script>
  customElements.define("vertical-layout", class extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
      super()
        .attachShadow({
          mode: "open"
        })
        .innerHTML =
        `<style>
         :host {
           display: flex;
           flex-direction: column;
           background:lightgreen;
           padding-left:20px;
           border:2px solid red;
         }
         ::slotted(*){margin-left:20px}
         :host([childmargin]) ::slotted(:not(:first-child)) {
           color:blue;
         }
       </style>
       &lt;slot>
       <slot></slot>
       &lt;/slot>`;
    }
    connectedCallback() {
      let margin = this.getAttribute("childmargin");
      setTimeout(() => {
        let children = [...this.querySelectorAll("*:not(:first-child)")];
        children.map(child=>{
          child.style.setProperty("--childmargin", margin);
          child.append(` margin-top: ${margin}`);
        })
      });
    }
  });

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for taking the time to do this, sorry I couldn't make the problem easier to understand. You've taught me lots of things here, your effort is *much* appreciated.