# CSS :host vs CSS Class in Web Components

Tags: css, web-component

With a normal React/Vue component I normally create a custom CSS class and use that to style the component like so:

```
<div class="foo">
  ...
</div>

.foo {
}
```

With web components, there is the additional option to use the `:host` psuedo-selector. I understand that it can be used to apply styles to the web component HTML element itself.

```
<div class="foo">
  ...
</div>

.foo {
}
:host {
}
```

When should I use `:host` versus a custom CSS class like `.foo`?

Answer (score 3):

An important part you do not mention, is that React (and other Frameworks), **in the build step**, *rewrites* all your classNames, to create "unique" class names.
React does not scope CSS like shadowDOM does.

Below answer is for a Web Component **with** shadowDOM;
Note that shadowDOM **can** be attached to regular DOM Elements as well. Same answer applies.

- `:host` refers to your ... host...Web Component DOM element: `<my-element>`
  Bluntly said, you could compare it to `html,head,body` in global CSS, it is the container element
  The CSS *inside* does **not** (have to) know the element **name** `my-element`
- classes (or any CSS selector you know) style Web Component **content**
  OR, if you are not using shadowDOM, they style your **whole** document,
  because **unlike** Frameworks, classNames are **not** changed, to be "unique", in the Build step.
- And do learn `<slot>`  behaviour:
  [::slotted CSS selector for nested children in shadowDOM slot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61626493/slotted-css-selector-for-nested-children-in-shadowdom-slot/61631668#61631668)

[image]

```html
<style>
 .foo {
   border:1px solid red; /* CSS not applied to elements in shadowDOM */
   font: 30px Arial; /* for UX consistancy, font styles DO style shadowDOM */
 }
</style>
<span class="foo">
  <my-element>Hello</my-element>
  Web Components
  <my-element pink>World</my-element>
</span>

<template id="MY-ELEMENT">
  <style>
    :host {
        display:inline-block;
        background:lightgreen;
    }
    :host([pink]) { background:hotpink }
    .foo { font-weight:bold; /* does NOT style anything outside this shadowDOM  */ }
  </style>
  <slot class="foo"></slot>
</template>

<script>
  customElements.define('my-element', class extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
      super().attachShadow({mode: 'open'})
             .append(document.getElementById(this.nodeName).content.cloneNode(true));
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Related to this question, what bothers me here is that I can't find a way to apply a class to the host, instead of using a <style> tag with :host pseuso-selector. 
It's currently trendy (again) to use class-based framework thanks to the wave of frameworks that modernized this pattern (Tailwind namely).

Comment: A Custom Element **is** an HTML Element, so accepts classes just like any other. Notation with class ``foo`` from _inside_ with a ``<style>`` tag would be something like: ``:host(.foo)`` Note that shadowDOM is all about **not** accepting global styles (or, equally important, no styles _leaking out_); if you want style inheritance, do **not use** shadowDOM.

Comment: In a an usual React component for instance, the root element is part of the render, so you can add classes to it: `() => <div className="text-blue">...</div>`. But a web component adds another level of indirection, so the tree looks like `() => <foo><div class="text-blue">...</div></foo>`. With className based styling you'd want "<foo class="text-blue"> with "text-blue" applied by the component itself, not the parent (that's the important part here) but I can't find anyway to do that.

Comment: In React the root element IS an HTMLElement, and only those can have classes. A shadowDOM (A construct that does not exist in React at all) is not an HTMLElement thus can not have classes. Comparing React and Web Components is _apples and oranges_. 
And like I said, if you don't like shadowDOM, then don't use it.