# When i add element from outside to web component its shows <div> reveal

Tags: web-component, shadow-dom, lit-element

When I add children to the web component from outside, adding  as reveal will it be a problem for it to benefit from the shadow dom?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

When the Custom Element has shadowDOM,

Slotted *lightDOM* content is **reflected** to `<slot>` elements in *shadowDOM*

The reveal button in F12 tools takes you to the **current slotted** *lightDOM* content

Also see: [::slotted CSS selector for nested children in shadowDOM slot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61626493/slotted-css-selector-for-nested-children-in-shadowdom-slot/61631668#61631668)

Comment: Also this documents help to me for understand [link](https://javascript.info/slots-composition)