# How to reach a Class in Shadowroot

Tags: javascript, shadow-dom

This might be a simple one, I'm trying to figure out how to reach the class "sn-inbox"

[image]

With the below code I could reach the child node of first shadow-root, but how do I get to the next Shadow-root, I should be then able to easily reach the class.

```
let Acceptbtn = $("[slot=primary-content-area")[4]?.shadowRoot?.childNodes[0];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell from your screenshot, `<sn-inbox>` is in the **lightDOM** of `<sn-ux-content-option`> (which has shadowDOM) And (I guess) is ***slotted*** to a `<slot>`?

You can use the `slotChange` Event to capture *when* content is slotted

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSlotElement/slotchange_event

OR access the DOM element **in lightDOM**

`let Acceptbtn = $("[slot=primary-content-area")[4]?.querySelector("sn-inbox");`

For in-depth slotted info see: [::slotted CSS selector for nested children in shadowDOM slot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61626493/slotted-css-selector-for-nested-children-in-shadowdom-slot/61631668#61631668)

Comment: I tried the above code but gets null value. I'm new to this slotted concept. As my screenshot is removed from post, not sure if I will get anymore help here.

Comment: I did not remove your screenshot; I changed the link to another site to an inline image. You probably have to get your selector right; I pasted it onto your original jQuery selector (I don't know jQuery syntax anymore). Learning takes time, takes a lot of trial and error. But the answer is understanding "lightDOM" and (slotted) "shadowDOM"

Comment: Thanks for that. I'm new to this shadowdom. I just want to know how to get into <sn-inbox component-id. There on I can get to the class easily.

Comment: That  element is in lightdom