# How to ensure CSS class styles are rendered on Custom HTML Elements?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, shadow-dom, custom-element

New to using custom HTML elements. My class style is not applying to the page render, though it shows in the DOM. The only clue is that it appears in the inspector within the open Shadow DOM rather than the regular DOM, which seems undesirable if it causes CSS issues.

Note the class style in question in this example is called 'border-all'. I have tried three modern browsers. No border displays

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>My Test</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" >
    <script src="header.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <header-component></header-component>
</body>
</html>
```

header.js

```
class Header extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    const template = document.createElement('template');
    const h1 = document.createElement('h1')
    h1.innerHTML = 'Hello World'
    h1.style.color = 'green'
    h1.className = 'border-all'
    template.content.appendChild(h1)
    const shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });
    shadowRoot.appendChild(template.content);
  }
}

customElements.define('header-component', Header);
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: hyperHTML is useful in my case and avoids this issue

Answer (score 4):

https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-components/shadowdom

ShadowDOM is styled by:

- `<style>` within shadowDOM
- Inheritable styles
  https://lamplightdev.com/blog/2019/03/26/why-is-my-web-component-inheriting-styles/
- (cascading) CSS properties
- shadowParts (and Themes)
  https://meowni.ca/posts/part-theme-explainer/
- `<slot>` are **reflected**, they are NOT styled by the shadowDOM, but by its container.
  See: [::slotted content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61626493/slotted-css-selector-for-nested-children-in-shadowdom-slot/61631668#61631668)
- (feb 2022) Constructible StyleSheets is still a Chromium only party
  https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_cssstylesheet_cssstylesheet

```js
customElements.define("my-component",class extends HTMLElement{
  constructor(){
    super().attachShadow({mode:"open"})
           .innerHTML = `
           <style>
             :host { display:inline-block; padding-left:2em }
             h2 { margin:0 }
             span {
                    color: var(--spancolor,grey);
           </style>
           <h2 part="wcTitle">Hello Web Component!</h2>
           <span>styling shadowDOM can be a challenge</span>
           <slot></slot>`;
  }
})
```

```html
<style>
  body {
    font:18px Arial; /* inheritable styles style Web Components */
    color:green; /* color is an inheritable style */
    --spancolor: lightcoral; /* css properties cascade, and are available in Web Components */
  }
  div ::part(wcTitle){ /* ::parts style ALL (nested) elements in shadowDOM */
    background:gold;
  }
  my-component{
    font-weight: bold; /* slotted content is styled by the container */
  }
   my-component my-component{
    color:blue;
  }
</style>

<my-component>But is very powerfull!</my-component>
<div>
  <my-component>You should never give up!
    <my-component>Those who quit after the first attempt are loosers</my-component>
  </my-component>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. Loser is spelt with a single 'o'. Contrast with loose, antonym of tight

Comment: That is the drawback, English is not my first language.

Answer (score -1):

One way of doing this is to use the [Element.classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) property

You can just:

```
document.querySelector('h1').classList.add('border-all');
```

I will leave you below a working example in CodePen, the only difference is that the element already have and id and we use
`document.getElementById`
instead of
`document.querySelector`

But thats pretty much the difference, I hope this helps you understand better!

https://codepen.io/Jeysoon/pen/NWwzEJG?editors=1111

Comment: Where is the Web Component with ShadowDOM OP (Original Poster) is using, in your codePen?