# Stenciljs: What is the right way to prepend/append Slot elements?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic-framework, web-component, stenciljs

I am having some trouble with the lifecycle methods in web components.

We want to dynamically order child elements being passed in as slots.

To illustrate, this web component takes a prop, `iconPos`, and will determine whether the icon will be placed at the start or end of the slot.

```
<my-component iconPos="start"> 
   <img src="/path/icon.svg" /> 
   <div>{this.list}</div> 
</my-component>
```

I haven't had any luck getting it working with `ref`:

`dc6b89e7.js:2926 TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'prepend')`

Here's what I have so far:

```
 @State() slotElement!: HTMLDivElement;
 @Prop() iconPos: 'start' | 'end';
...

  private createSlots() {
    switch (this.iconPos) {
      case 'start':
        this.slotElement.prepend(<img />);
        break;
      case 'end':
        this.slotElement.append(<img />);
        break;
      default:
        throw new Error(
          `Invalid value \`${this.iconPos}\`, passed into \`iconPos\`. Expected valid values are \`start\`, \`end\``.
        );
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
    // iconPos="start"
      <parent-component>
        <div ref={(el) => (this.slotElement= el as HTMLDivElement)}>
          <slot></slot>
        </div>
      </parent-component>
    )
  }
```

I would prefer to not use a CSS solution if possible. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Slotted content is **NOT MOVED** to `<slot>` elements; it is **reflected!!**

So all styling and element operations must be done in "lightDOM"

For (very) long read see:
[::slotted CSS selector for nested children in shadowDOM slot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61626493/slotted-css-selector-for-nested-children-in-shadowdom-slot/61631668#61631668)

That means you have to `append` your elements in ligtDOM with:

`this.append(this.firstElementChild)`

You can't read the `<my-component>` innerHTML **before** it is parsed; so you need to wait till the innerHTML elements are created. Thus you will see the DOM change.
A better method might be to not use `<slot>` and declare your icon and content as **attributes**, and have the Web Component **create** the HTML.

```html
<style>
  span::after { content: attr(id) }
  #FOO { background: lightgreen }
</style>

<my-component>
  <span id="FOO"></span>
  <span id="BAR"></span>
</my-component>
<my-component reversed>
  <span id="FOO"></span>
  <span id="BAR"></span>
</my-component>

<script>
  window.customElements.define('my-component', class extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
      super().attachShadow({mode:'open'})
             .innerHTML = `<style>::slotted(span){background:gold}</style>
                           ${this.nodeName}<slot></slot><br>`;
    }
    connectedCallback() {
      setTimeout(() => { // make sure innerHTML is parsed!
        if (this.hasAttribute("reversed")) {
          this.append(this.firstElementChild);
        }
      })
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Ah okay.. what if the web component will have nested child components? 

If I am understanding correctly, are saying it will wait for ALL children to be parsed before the `this.append(this.firstElementChild);` is called like in your `setTimeout()` call  example?   

Is there any reason why you would use setTimeout() over `CustomElementRegistry.whenDefined()`?

Comment: Whendefined test if the component was defined with javascript,  it has nothing to do with DOM elements