# Style Web Components via Attributes or Custom Styles

Tags: html, css, web-component, native-web-component

I have a web component *my-icon*. The component wraps an icon-font and some "business related" ui-logic to choose the correct icon by the given name:

```
<my-icon name="arrow-left" />
```

The user can also decide which size and color the icon should have. What is the right way to provide this functionality?

- Custom styles *--my-icon-color* and *--my-icon-size*
- Properties + Attributes for color and size
- Both

Currently I provide both, but I'm not sure if it's a good practice to "style" a component via attributes and properties. On the other hand it may ease the use of the component (e.g. change the color via Data-Binding).

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There is no best practice, there are multiple ways to style shadowDOM, which one you use is up to you.

ShadowDOM is styled by:

- `<style>` within shadowDOM
- Inheritable styles
  https://lamplightdev.com/blog/2019/03/26/why-is-my-web-component-inheriting-styles/
- (cascading) CSS properties
- shadowParts (and Themes)
  https://meowni.ca/posts/part-theme-explainer/
- `<slot>` are **reflected**, they are NOT styled by the shadowDOM, but by its container.
  See: [::slotted content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61626493/slotted-css-selector-for-nested-children-in-shadowdom-slot/61631668#61631668)
- (feb 2022) Constructible StyleSheets is still a Chromium only party
  https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_cssstylesheet_cssstylesheet
- your custom directive

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But i was rather looking for a best practice to provide a styling API for the users of my component.