# Preact in the Shadow DOM but lost all styles

Tags: reactjs, shadow-dom, preact

I'm building a widget and hence wanted to load the widget Preact app in the shadow DOM to avoid CSS conflicts.

I am succesfully able to do so like this.

```
 const host = document.querySelector('#widget-_hw');
 const shadow = host?.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });
 const renderIn = document.createElement('div');
 shadow?.appendChild(renderIn);
 render(h(App, { ...config, element: el }), renderIn)
```

But lost all styles.

I have all styles required for Widget inside a file called main.css. Where I have all styles defined like this

```
reset {
  composes: scope;
  background: var(--color-bg);
  color: var(--color-text);
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto,
    Oxygen-Sans, Ubuntu, Cantarell, "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}

.reset h1,
.reset h2,
.reset h3,
.reset h4,
.reset h5,
.reset h6 {
  line-height: var(--line-height);
}

//and many other like button, input fields, containers etc
```

Could someone suggest me a way to import style elements back into the preact app?

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of shadowDOM is to NOT be styled by global/outside CSS

ShadowDOM is styled by:

- `<style>` within shadowDOM
- Inheritable styles
  https://lamplightdev.com/blog/2019/03/26/why-is-my-web-component-inheriting-styles/
- (cascading) CSS properties
- shadowParts (and Themes)
  https://meowni.ca/posts/part-theme-explainer/
- `<slot>` are **reflected**, they are NOT styled by the shadowDOM, but by its container.
  See: [::slotted content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61626493/slotted-css-selector-for-nested-children-in-shadowdom-slot/61631668#61631668)
- (feb 2022) Constructible StyleSheets is still a Chromium only party
  https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_cssstylesheet_cssstylesheet
- your custom directive