# How to rerender a custom element?

Tags: javascript, custom-element

I created a header element which at its initial state shows loading

```
export const FmHeader = (data) => {
  fetch("../../templates/fm-header/index.html")
    .then((response) => response.text())
    .then((html) => HeaderElement(html));
};

const HeaderElement = (html, data) => {
  class FmHeader extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
      super();

      var el = this.attachShadow({ mode: "open" });
      el.innerHTML = html;
      if (data) {
        const artistName = el.querySelector(".artist_name");
        artistName.innerText = "data.artistName;";
        artistName.classList.remove("skeleton");
      }
    }
  }

  customElements.define("fm-header", FmHeader);
};
```

I'm calling it like so:

```
(function(){ 
    FmHeader();
    setTimeout(() => {
        FmHeader({data: 'some data from server'});
    }, 1000);
})()
```

I understand the error - that the same element can't be redefined. But is there a way to achieve something like this?

A basic [code pen version](https://codepen.io/cezme4/pen/xxYLqLq?editors=1011)

Comment: Use the [<>] button in the editor, and create an executable SO snippet, not many people will copy/paste your code parts and make it work

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman I can't get that to work, it throws `ReferenceError: HTMLElements is not defined` error

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman I create a code pen https://codepen.io/cezme4/pen/xxYLqLq?editors=1011

Comment: Your code tries the ``define("fm-header", `` a second time (for every call to ``FmHeader``) You can't do that; Custom Elements can only be defined **once**, and can not be removed.

Answer (score 0):

- Add content to Web Components with data-attributes, and `<slot>` (only in shadowDOM)
- Attributes are only available in the `connectedCallback`, as the `constructor` can run when the Element is **not** in the DOM (eg. `document.createElement("my-artist")`
- Multiple styling options, see: [::slotted CSS selector for nested children in shadowDOM slot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61626493/slotted-css-selector-for-nested-children-in-shadowdom-slot/61631668#61631668)

```js
customElements.define("my-artist", class extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super()
     .attachShadow({mode:"open"})
     .innerHTML = `<style>`+
     `::slotted([slot="instruments"]) { background: gold }`+
     `</style>`+
     `<h1 part='artistname'></h1>`+
     `<div part='instruments'>Played: <slot name="instruments">No instruments specified</slot></div>`+
     `<slot>some facts here</slot>`+
     ``;
  }
  connectedCallback(){
    this
     .shadowRoot
     .querySelector("[part='artistname']")
     .innerText = this.getAttribute("name");
  }
});
```

```css
*::part(artistname){
  /* style shadowDOM parts from global CSS */
  font-size:1.2em;
  margin:0;
  background:blue;
  color:gold;
}
body{
  font:12px Arial; /* inheritable styles DO style shadowDOM*/
}
```

```html
<my-artist name="John">John was my favorite!
  <span slot="instruments">Many instruments</span>
</my-artist>
<my-artist name="Paul"></my-artist>
<my-artist name="George">
   <span slot="instruments">drums</span>
</my-artist>
<my-artist name="Ringo"><span slot="instruments">drums</span></my-artist>
```

##### Notes:

- note how the slot **order** is maintained (see John)
- George does **not** show the default `some facts here`, because the `<my-artist>` **innerHTML** contains spaces (and linebreaks); which get slotted to the default/unnamed `<slot>`