# CSS: How add hover effect to ::slotted in Shadow DOM root and

Tags: css, shadow-dom, slot

I have have shadow DOM element,

```
<div>
     <slot name="item"> <i class="icon-name"> </i> </slot>
</div>
```

I wanted to have hover effect to "Icon" how to write hover effect for slot element ?

Comment: slotted content is styled in **lightDOM** See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61626493/slotted-css-selector-for-nested-children-in-shadowdom-slot/61631668#61631668

Comment: Note: your code is not the result of slotting content; slotted content is **reflected** to a ``<slot>`` NOT copied or moved

Answer (score 1):

This only works with css in the Shadow Dom.
I found it here: https://codepen.io/smspp/pen/EzYGpa

```
::slotted(*:hover)
```