# Styling elements inside shadow root

Tags: css, shadow-dom, shadow-root

I'm trying to style an element inside of a shadow dom. I've tried a couple of things, namely the following:

Using JS:

```
document.querySelector('#select-input').shadowRoot.getElementById('#aab-select-label');
```

This returns an error stating: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'setAttribute')

Using CSS:

```
  #select-input::shadow .mb-1 #aab-select-label {
    height: 20px !important;
  }

  #select-input /deep/ .mb-1 #aab-select-label {
    height: 20px !important;
  }
```

But these selectors also don't apply any styling for some reason. The shadow root is open as far as I can see:

[image]

Does anyone know how I should style this?

Answer (score 0):

The whole purpose of shadowDOM is to scope styling.

Technologies like `/deep/` where Google only parties and never made into a standard supported in other browsers.

The answers in [::slotted CSS selector for nested children in shadowDOM slot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61626493/slotted-css-selector-for-nested-children-in-shadowdom-slot/61631668#61631668) reference a lot of the modern possibilities:

- slots
- Inheritable styles
- CSS Properties
- Parts
- Themes

Note: your `querySelector(...).shadowRoot` should work on an `open` shadowRoot. Please create a minimal example with the [<>] button in the editor, so we can see running code.