# Is it possible to add elements within a custom element without using `<template>` and template slots?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, shadow-dom

I'm trying to create a custom component which can take other HTML Elements, however, it has to be flexible by not having to use `<template>` and slots templates in the HTML file every time the component is used. Already tried querying after every render by using `const children = this.shadow.querySelectorAll('.menu > *')` within the `connectedCallback()` function, but the result is an empty `NodeList`

```js
class SideMenu extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.shadow = this.attachShadow({mode:'open'});
    }

    render() {
        this.shadow.innerHTML = `
        <style>
          .menu {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            height: 100vh;
            padding: 2em;
            width: 33vw;
            gap: 10px;
            background-color: #2C2B2B;
          }
        </style>
        <div class="menu">
        </div>
        `;
    }

    connectedCallback() {
        this.render();
    }
}

customElements.define('side-menu', SideMenu);
```

```html
<side-menu>
    <div>Element1</div>
    <div>Element2</div>
    <div>Element3</div>
    <div>ElementN</div>
</side-menu>
```

Basically, the custom element has to be able to have any number of elements within, like an unordered list (`<ul>`) which can have multiple `<li>` inside.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You have a shadowDOM, so don't need an extra `div` when you style the component with `:host`
- you can manually move ligthDOM elements to shadowDOM
- `super()` sets AND returns the 'this' scope
- `attachShadow` sets AND returns `this.shadowRoot`
- `append` wasn't available in Internet Explorer, ("oldfashioned" devs still use `appendChild`)
  note it **moves** the DOM elements from lightDOM to shadowDOM. And if you ***move*** Web Components, the `connectedCallback` will run **again** (but lightDOM will then be empty) So be aware what you do in the `connectedCallback`

```js
customElements.define('side-menu', class extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super().attachShadow({mode:'open'}).innerHTML = `
        <style>
          :host {
            display: flex; flex-direction: column; gap: 10px;
            height: 100vh; width: 33vw;
            padding: 2em;
            background-color: #2C2B2B; color: gold;
          }
        </style>`;
    }

    connectedCallback() {
        this.shadowRoot.append(...this.children);
    }
});
```

```html
<side-menu>
    <div>Element1</div>
    <div>Element2</div>
    <div>Element3</div>
    <div>ElementN</div>
</side-menu>
```

Comment: Is there any way to keep the styling from the elements that were in the lightDOM after passing them to shadowDOM?

Comment: ?? Elements in lightDOM are styled; but you don't want that styling? Slotted elements are **not** moved, they are **reflected** into ``<slot>`` thus remain being styled in lightDOM. If you remove the style you remove all styling. You can style slotted content; deep dive: [StackOverflow: ::slotted styling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61626493/slotted-css-selector-for-nested-children-in-shadowdom-slot/61631668#61631668)

Comment: I reread you question; You can also create ``<style>`` inside shadowDOM yourself. There is no option to do: Take ALL styling of an element and move it to shadowDOM, the whole point of shadowDOM is encapsulation. Don't use shadowDOM when you want global CSS to style content