# How to reference a Stenciljs <slot /> from the HTML page?

Tags: stenciljs, slot, slots

In case I have multiple `<slot />`s nested inside my Stencil component, I would need to give them names, and then reference them inside my HTML page when using that component. So, how do I do that?

Example:

```
  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <button><slot name="one" /></button>
        <select>
          <option value="one"><slot name="two" /></option>
        </select>
        <p> <slot name="three" /></p>
      </div>
    )
  }
```

And then when I am adding this component, how do I add content to each `<slot />`?

I have tried what is explained here: `https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/slot`
but it's not working!
I have tried the following in my HTML page:

```
<span slot="two">dfdf</span> 
<slot name="two"><span>gdgdg</span></slot>
```

Neither work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example in the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/slot) is about as clear as you can get.
I only *deleted* content from the example <template> to focus on just the <slot> elements:

```js
customElements.define("slot-example", class extends HTMLElement{
  constructor(){
    super()
     .attachShadow({mode:"open"})
     .append(document.getElementById(this.nodeName).content.cloneNode(true));
  }
});
```

```html
<template id="SLOT-EXAMPLE">
  <style>span { color:red }</style>
  <slot name="element-name">NEED NAME</slot>
  <span><slot name="description">NEED DESCRIPTION</slot></span>
  <slot name="attributes"><p>None</p></slot>
</template>

<slot-example>
  <span slot="element-name">slot-example</span>
  <span slot="description">This demonstrates slot</span>
</slot-example>

<slot-example>
  <b slot="element-name">another slot-example</b>
  <b slot="attributes">Explain to yourself why this is bold and not a paragraph</slot>
</slot-example>
```

For a deep, deep, very deep dive into styling slots with ::slotted see:  [::slotted CSS selector for nested children in shadowDOM slot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61626493/slotted-css-selector-for-nested-children-in-shadowdom-slot/61631668#61631668)

### Addition after comments

Here some inspiration to get you started:

```js
customElements.define("my-select", class extends HTMLElement{
  connectedCallback(){
    setTimeout(()=>{ // ! wait till innerHTML is parsed
      this.innerHTML = 
          "<SELECT>" + 
          this.innerHTML
              .split("\n")
              .filter(Boolean)
              .map(company=>`<OPTION>${company.trim()}</OPTION>`);
          "</SELECT>";
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<my-select>
Apple
Microsoft
Google
Mozilla
</my-select>
```

Comment: I'm sorry but how is that different from what I did? The only difference is that my web components are made in Stencil, where as you are doing them with JS. Also, you are adding the slots in Vue, and I am adding them in HTML. I have heard that you cannot name slots in the light DOM, but only in the shadow DOM. So that could explain why is it not working for me.

Comment: ???!!! This **is** native JS and HTML code, not Vue. You _name_ SLOTs in shadowDOM with the ``name`` attribute, you _target/assign_ SLOTs in lightDOM with the ``slot`` attribute

Comment: I just discovered that the issue is the element I am trying to put a slot in. Naming slots work, but not in `<select><option></select>` for some reason.

Comment: Ah! Yes, ``<select>`` itself is implemented as a Web Component in all browsers (but not a _User Defined_ Web Component) (You can tell by Inspecting it in the Browser; you will see a ``#shadowRoot (user-agent)`` And it only accepts ``<option>`` elements. You can not slot anything into there. So built the ``<option>`` content yourself.

Comment: But my <slot /> is inside the <option> element. I have this `<option><slot name="one" /></option>` inside `<select>`, and then from my HTTML, I pass content like this `<span slot="one">first selection</span>` inside the component. So, why is it not working? I am just adding the span? But anyway, if this doesn't work, how else can I do it? What do you mean by `build the <option> content yourself`? Isn't that what I am doing when I just pass the `<span>` to the slot?

Comment: Just to be clear, `<option slot="inside">` does not work for `<select><slot name="inside" /></select>`, and `<span slot="inside">` also does not work for `<select><option><slot name="inside" /></option></select>`.

Comment: You can't use ``slot`` on or inside ``<option>``. In technical terms: you can't cross ``user-agent`` shadow-roots with ``user-defined`` content. Not in ``<select>`` not in ``<textarea>`` not in UX components where Browser Vendors have implemented their own (thus "user-agent") code. And, yes, the documentation on this knowledge sucks.

Comment: Okay.. So, what do I do then? How can I do it? Is creating a custom dropdown/select the only solution?

Comment: or built the whole ``SELECT`` and ``OPTION`` Children **HTML** yourself;

Comment: Okay, last question. How do I add a class now to the slotted element? I understand that you can't have a `class` on the <slot />. So, if I pass `<select slot="myslot" class="something>` why is the class not working when it's rendered?

Comment: Make it a new question, and include a working SO snippet (that [<>] button in the SO editor)

Comment: I posted a new question, please take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75131443/how-do-i-add-a-class-to-a-slotted-element