# How can I target class inside shadow root without JS?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Let's say I have html element with shadow root.

```
<my-element>
#shadow-root
<div class='need-target-this' />
</my-element>
```

How can I target div inside shadow root?

I've tried to use

```
:host(my-element.need-target-this)
```

But it didn't help. What am I missing here?

Comment: We need the complete code, are slots involved? Do you want to target from _inside_ or _outside_ the shadowRoot?

Comment: no slots, and inside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case it will help some one: I wrapped my element with `div` added `ref` and then went

`const shadow = ref.current.querySelector('my-element').shadowRoot`

`const target = shadow?.querySelector('.need-target-this')`

`target.style.whatever = 'value';`

Answer (score 1):

- Style shadowDOM with `<style>` tags **inside** shadowDOM
- also see **::part**: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::part
- also see: [::slotted CSS selector for nested children in shadowDOM slot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61626493/slotted-css-selector-for-nested-children-in-shadowdom-slot/61631668#61631668)

```js
customElements.define("my-element",class extends HTMLElement{
  constructor(){
    super().attachShadow({mode:"open"}).innerHTML = `
    <style>
      .target { background:hotpink; border: 5px dashed green }
      ::slotted(span) {
        color : red;
      }
    </style>
    <slot name="title"></slot>
    <span part="mytarget" class='target' />`;
  }
  connectedCallback(){
    this.shadowRoot.querySelector("span").innerHTML = `Web Component!`;
  }
});
```

```html
<style>
  * { font: 42px Arial }
  span {
    background:gold; /* slot content styled by Global CSS! */
  }
  .target { border: 5px solid blue } /* does NOT style shadowDOM! */
  
  my-element::part(mytarget) {
    font-size: 150%;
  }
</style>

<my-element class="target"><span slot="title">Hello</span>

</my-element>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it wouldn't help. 

I'm using 3rd party package for Next.js, that's why I need override styles, forgot to mention it.

Anyway, thanks for your time

Comment: If you have script access you can inject anything of the above

Comment: I will go with ```document.querySelector``` and overriding styles solution, but thank you anyway.

Was just wondering if it could be done with pure CSS.