# Using slots in WebComponents without using shadow DOM

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, web-component

I'm trying to build a WebComponent without using ShadowDOM - so far it mostly just worked, but now I want to build a component that wraps other components like you would do with Angular's `@ViewChild` / `@ViewChildren`. (the library I'm using here to render is uhtml similar to lit-html)

```
export class Dropdown extends HTMLElement {

    private open: boolean = false;

    static observedAttributes = ["open"]

    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    attributeChangedCallback(name: string, oldValue: string, newValue: string) {
        switch (name) {
            case "open":
                this.open = Boolean(newValue);
                break;
        }
        this.display()
    }

    connectedCallback() {
        this.display()
    }

    display = () => {
        render(this, html`
            <div>
                <slot name="item">

                </slot>
            </div>
        `)
    }

    static register = () => customElements.define("my-dropdown", Dropdown)

}
```

If I now use this component

```
Dropdown.register();


render(document.body, html`
    <my-dropdown open="true">
        <strong slot="item">test</strong>
    </my-dropdown>

`)
```

I'm expecting to see

```
<my-dropdown>
    <div>
        <strong>test</test>
    </div>
</my-dropdown>
```

but the slot part is not working.

If I switch to ShadowDOM, it just works, but now I have to deal with ShadowDOM's sandbox with regards to styling which I'd rather not do.

```
constructor() {
    super();
    this.attachShadow({mode: "open"})
}
```

```
display = () => {
    render(this.shadowRoot as Node, html`
```

Is it possible to make slots work without shadowDOM?
If not, is there different way to grab the content defined inside the component and use it inside display?

```
<my-component>
    <div>some content here</div>
</my-component>
```

should render as

```
<my-component>
    <header>
        random header
    </header>
    <section>
        <!-- my custom content -->
        <div>some content here</div>
    </section>
</my-component>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: No, ``<slot>`` are part of the shadowDOM API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, `<slot>` are part of the shadowDOM API

You can fake it, but since there is no shadowDOM you would have to store that content someplace else.
Could be a `<template>` you read and parse your (light)DOM content into.

That is a sh*load of DOM mutations.
Might be easier to just learn to style shadowDOM with:

- CSS properties
- inheritable styles
- ::slotted
- ::part
- constructable stylesheets

Comment: and the content inside that slot is changing depending on state which would make the stored content stale. Pity, I was just getting excited that I've escaped ShadowDOM and could style things globally. Guess I'll go back to ShadowDOM

Comment: And don't forget [::slotted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61626493/slotted-css-selector-for-nested-children-in-shadowdom-slot/61631668#61631668)