# How to access the data inside a SLOT in web-components (aka: custom components) with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, native-web-component

Im trying to understand how I can use `<slot>` properly. I made this example which I would like to be able to access the qty from the tag `<li name="qty">102</li>`, which has been exposed as a named slot in the web-component as `<slot name="qty"></slot>`

Running this example:

```js
const template = document.createElement('template');
    template.innerHTML = `
    <style>
    slot{
        color: blue;
    }
    </style>
    
    <p>
        <slot></slot>
        <ul>
            <slot name="component"></slot>
            <slot name="qty"></slot>
        </ul>
    </p>
    `
    class SlotTest extends HTMLElement {
        constructor(){
            super();
            let shadow = this.attachShadow({mode: "open"});
            this.shadowRoot.appendChild( template.content.cloneNode(true) );
        }
        connectedCallback(){
            this.shadowRoot.querySelectorAll("slot").forEach(element => {
                if (element.name === '') {
                    console.info("unamed slot", element)
                } else{
                    console.info(`slot.innerText = "${element.innerHTML}"`, element)
                }
    
            });
        }
    }
    
    window.customElements.define('track-comp', SlotTest);
```

```html
<track-comp>
<h2>TLC555CP</h2>
<li name="component">Timer IC</li>
<li name="qty">55</li>
</track-comp>
    
<track-comp>
<h2>2N2369</h2>
<li name="component">High Speed Switching Transistor</li>
<li name="qty">102</li>
</track-comp>
```

The innerText or HTML of the slot does not seem to be accessible.  Is there a way to see this or do you have to add another property describing the quantity?  And as for the un-nmed slot; how is that accessed inside the web component?

[image]

**EDIT**

I accept the answer but just wanted to share the correct thing would be to add an event listener like this in the constructor and handle the update that way.

```
this.shadowRoot.addEventListener('slotchange', event => console.log('event', event.target, this.nodeName, this.innerText));
```

So something like this would allow me to react to the slot update and view the slot content.

```
this.shadowRoot.addEventListener('slotchange', event => {
                console.info(this.nodeName);
                console.info(this.innerHTML);
            });
```

please take a look at [this example](https://github.com/mdn/web-components-examples/tree/main/slotchange) for further details on slots

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Slotted content is ***reflected*** to shadowDOM, NOT ***moved*** to shadowDOM

For very very long answer see: [::slotted CSS selector for nested children in shadowDOM slot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61626493/slotted-css-selector-for-nested-children-in-shadowdom-slot/61631668#61631668)

That means your slotted content **remains in lightDOM**

And it is just a regular DOM operation:

```js
get quantity(){
    return ~~this.querySelector(`[name="qty"]`)?.innerHTML;
}
```

But be careful; if you component is *defined* **before** the Web Component lightDOM is *parsed*;  as shown in the SO snippet below,
you can not access lightDOM immediately, you have to wait for the innerHTML to be parsed (aka the Event Loop is empty) with `setTimeout` or `requestAnimationFrame`. BaseClasses like Lit, Stencil, LWC etc. will do this for you under de hood and provided you with an `adoptedCallback` (or something similar named)

```html
<script>
customElements.define('track-comp', class extends HTMLElement {
  constructor(){
    super()
    .attachShadow({mode: "open"})
    .innerHTML = `<style>slot{color: blue}</style>
                  <p>
                    <slot></slot>
                    <ul>
                      <slot name="component"></slot>
                      <slot name="qty"></slot>
                    </ul>
                  </p>`;
  }
  get quantity(){
    return ~~this.querySelector(`[name="qty"]`)?.innerHTML;
  }
  connectedCallback(){
    console.log(this.nodeName,this.quantity);
    setTimeout(()=>{
      console.log(this.nodeName,this.quantity);
    });
  }
});
</script>

<track-comp>
  <h2>TLC555CP</h2>
  <li name="component">Timer IC</li>
  <li name="qty">55</li>
</track-comp>
<track-comp>
  <h2>2N2369</h2>
  <li name="component">High Speed Switching Transistor</li>
  <li name="qty">102</li>
</track-comp>
```

Comment: Thank You for that answer which by the way is not obvious from everything Ive read about this.

Comment: See that link to my very very long SO Answer. Google originally called it _distributed Nodes_ I coined the phrase _**reflected**_ which also explains why ``::slotted`` can only style the outer part, its like painting lipstick on the (shadowDOM) mirror

Comment: OK in short lightDOM becomes the children of component (this.childNodes) rather than being accessed in this.shadowDOM.

Comment: based on your hints i found [this](https://coryrylan.com/blog/understanding-slot-updates-with-web-components)   which is the 1st time ive seen an example like this. So thank you