# Unable to select <slot> using CSS Selector, how to style it to make "Launch" text color red?

Tags: sass, css-selectors, web-component, native-web-component, shoelace

[image]

As per above screenshot, I am trying to style web component , and content inside slot reveal/pointing to "Launch" when clicked. How can I style slot to apply text colour to "Launch". I am struggling to select slot using css selector. Any help/suggestions would be helpful.

I already tried to apply style using below selector but did not work for me.

`sl-tab::part(base)::slotted(*) { color: red; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to style Launch with another way using:

```
sl-tab[active]::part(base) {
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Slotted content is **not moved** to shadowDOM, therefor you can not style it **from** shadowDOM

##### Slotted content is *reflected* to shadowDOM

Slotted (lightDOM) content is styled by the container/level the **lightDOM** is in, in this case global CSS (see H1 and span styling)

`::slotted(span)` can only style the ***skin*** of lightDOM content, not DOM levels deeper (only span2 is styled)

Style slotted text with an `[attribute]` on the host element (see `launched`)

```js
customElements.define("component-with-slot",class extends HTMLElement{
  constructor(){
    super().attachShadow({mode:"open"}).innerHTML = 
     `<style>
        *::slotted(span) { padding:2em } 
        :host([launched])  { color:red; font-weight:bold }
      </style>` +
     `<slot></slot>`;
  }
});
```

```css
/* global CSS */
h1 {
  border:5px solid blue
}
span {
  border:4px dashed red;
}
```

```html
<component-with-slot>
  <h1>I am slotted <span>span1</span></h1>
  <span>span2</span>
</component-with-slot>

<component-with-slot launched>
  Launch happened
</component-with-slot>
```

For very detailed info see: [::slotted CSS selector for nested children in shadowDOM slot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61626493/slotted-css-selector-for-nested-children-in-shadowdom-slot/61631668#61631668)