# Web Component #shadow-root css leaks to document

Tags: html, css, web-component, shadow-dom

My understanding of web components was that you can use it to prevent css leaks from the web component to the parent. I need exactly that but for some reason styling inside the web component affects the whole document.

My current pairing buddy (ChatGPT) also doesn't understand what is happening .

```html
    <template id="test-shadow-dom-template">
        <slot name="menu-bar"></slot>
        <span id="contents">
            <slot>The content</slot>
        </span>
    </template>
```

```js
   <script type="text/javascript">
        if(!customElements.get('test-shadow-dom')) {
            customElements.define('test-shadow-dom', class extends HTMLElement {
                constructor() {
                    super();

                    let template = document.getElementById("test-shadow-dom-template");
                    let templateContent = template.content;

                    const shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
                    shadowRoot.appendChild(templateContent.cloneNode(true));
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
```

```html
<div id="test-shadow-dom-container" class="box" style="height: 100%">
    <test-shadow-dom id="my-id">
        <style>
            * {
                font-style: italic;
            }
        </style>
        <h1>Here is the actual contents...</h1>
    </test-shadow-dom>
</div>
```

### Chrome Developer tools

[image: Chrome developer tools]

My understanding is that only the contents of the `test-shadow-dom` would be italic yet everything on the webpage is *italic*.

Any idea what is going on?

Comment: You haven't created a web component with Javascript to use.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand your comment - the javascript for the custom element is also here in the SO Post? I also see the custom web component with it's shadow root in Chrome developer tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [my long explanation on ::slotted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61626493/slotted-css-selector-for-nested-children-in-shadowdom-slot/61631668#61631668)

**Slotted content remains in lightDOM, it is *reflected* to shadowDOM `<slot>`**
it is **NOT *moved* to shadowDOM `<slot>`**.

Thus your `<style>` styles the global document, just like it would when placed inside a `<div>`

Note ***inheritable (global) styles*** (see long ::slotted post) DO style shadowDOM.
`font-style` IS an inheritable style.

You can put the `<style>` inside the `<template>`; I omitted it for brievity.

Also note a **slotted** `<style>` does NOT style the shadowDOM it is in (red border)

```html
<div class="foo">This is my-element:</div>

<my-element>
  <style>
  * { /* in lightDOM, styles all of global DOM */
    font-style: italic; 
  }
  </style>
  <style>
    div {
      border: 2px solid red;
    }
  </style>
  my-element
</my-element>

<script>
customElements.define("my-element", class extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super()
            .attachShadow({ mode: "open" })
            .innerHTML = `<style>
                            * { /* in shadowDOM, styles only shadowDOM */
                              color:green;
                              font-weight: bold; 
                            }
                          </style>
                          <div>Hello!</div>
                          <slot></slot>`;
    }
})
</script>
```

You do have control of what users put in lightDOM, but only after all those elements are parsed (in lightDOM) can you access those elements from the `connectedCallback`.

Provided that lightDOM isn't huge (like say 500+ elements) a basic `setTimeout` will be enough to delay and execute code after parsing:

```js
connectedCallback() {
  setTimeout( () => {
    console.log( this.innerHTML );
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks fir this excellent explanation! Is there a way with web components where other developers will put style elements inside this web component to contain these styles so that the global document is not affected?

Comment: Doable, put the ``<style>`` tags in lightDOM. Mark them (with your own attribute) ``<style shadowRoot>`` to flag them to be **moved** to shadowRoot with a simple ``.append(...)`` For inspiration see the ``<load-file>`` Web Component [I blogged about on Dev,to](https://dev.to/dannyengelman/load-file-web-component-add-external-content-to-the-dom-1nd) BUT you will have to deal with FOUCs, because first global DOM is styled; and then "unstyled" Maybe better to educate users to use ``<template>``

Answer (score 0):

You should add styles inside template, not the component.

```
 <template id="test-shadow-dom-template">
   <style>
     * {
       font-style: italic;
     }
   </style>
   <slot name="menu-bar"></slot>
   <span id="contents">
   <slot>The content</slot>
 </span>
```

Or, you can just set the css inside javascript:

```
const style = document.createElement("style");
style.textContent = "* {font-style: italic}";
shadow.appendChild(style);
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/k8fxtacw/

Comment: Thanks for your input! The thing is that I will not have control over what other devs will put in the web component and I wanted to make sure that it doesn't affect the rest of the webpage.
An iframe is not an option so I wanted to try out web component but it looks like that will also not work?