# Custom Elements + Shadow Dom - styling the last child child of a named slot

Tags: shadow-dom

I am trying to apply a style to the last child of a named slot, and am struggling with getting the correct selector.

Essentially, `last-child` seems to apply in the light DOM, and not the shadow DOM, and thus will select the last slotted element regardless of which slot it is in, which may or may not even be valid given the scope of the selector.

Working fiddle here that demonstrates this: https://jsfiddle.net/w8rLghs7/29/

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, hope you will find new knowledge here. You can help us answering your question, by adding a [minimal-reproducible-example StackOverflow Snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It will help readers execute your code with one click. And help create answers with one click. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The most readable is to wrap you DIV menu items in a container `#lefties`

- You primarily style slots in **lightDOM**, not in shadowDOM
- `::slotted` does not take complex selectors;
  `::slotted([slot]:last-child)` is not a simple selector
  see the very long read: [::slotted CSS selector for nested children in shadowDOM slot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61626493/slotted-css-selector-for-nested-children-in-shadowdom-slot/61631668#61631668)

```html
<style>
  #lefties div:last-child {
    background-color: lime;
  }
</style>

<my-element>
  <div id="lefties" slot="lefties">
    <div>Menu 1</div>
    <div>Menu 2</div>
    <div>Menu 3</div>
  </div>
  <div>Main default &lt;slot></div>
</my-element>

<script>
  customElements.define("my-element", class extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
      super().attachShadow({mode: 'open'})
             .innerHTML = `<slot name='lefties'></slot><slot></slot>`
    }
  })
</script>
```

##### Re: comments

Since `:slotted` can only take *simple* selectors you can change the `Menu Item` to a *simple* selector `<menu-item>` to make `::slotted` work:

Note: `::slotted([slot]:last-of-type)` looks like a bug to me. It does style other named Custom Elements, it does not style the ** DIV Menu 6** (which I expect it should)

```html
<my-element>
  <menu-item slot="left">Menu 1</menu-item>
  <menu-item slot="left">Menu 2</menu-item>
  <menu-item slot="left">Menu 3</menu-item>
  <menu-item slot="left">Menu 4</menu-item>
  <div slot="left">Menu 5</div>
  <div slot="left">Menu 6</div>
  <div>Main default &lt;slot></div>
</my-element>

<script>
  customElements.define("menu-item", class extends HTMLElement {
    connectedCallback(){
      this.style.display = "block";
    }
  })
  customElements.define("my-element", class extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
      super().attachShadow({mode: 'open'})
             .innerHTML = 
             `<style>::slotted(menu-item:last-of-type){background:lime}</style>` +
             `<style>::slotted([slot]:last-of-type){color:red}</style>` +
             `<slot name='left'></slot><slot></slot>`
    }
  })
</script>
```

Comment: Hi.  Thanks for the link, I will dig into it.
Your example doesn't actually work - the nested items are not being put into the left slot, their wrapper div is being put into the unnamed slot, so although your styling appears to be working as desired, your slots are not.

Comment: See my addition to make ``::slotted`` work with a simple selector and using ``last-of-type``

Comment: Thanks for trying.  After reading the provided link, I think what I am trying to have happen is just not possible given the limitations of ::slotted()

Your example only works because all of the elements in the left slot are the same element type - using arbitrary elements (or divs for everything) would not work.

Comment: Regarding your "bug" with last-of-type, I understand your confusion - it's quite similar to my original confusion/question.  The last sibling div is the Main Default div, which does not have a [slot] attribute and thus is not included in the selector, and not actually styled.  If it was the last-of-type included in the original selector, it would work as you expect.   

Similarly to my original question, if it was the last-child _included in the original selector_, it would work as you expected.

Here's a simple example demonstrating this https://jsfiddle.net/Lbt7q8x4/1/

Comment: Interesting; its all about Node **types**. Alternative, but requires some code, is to catch the ``slotchange`` events and proces whats being slotted