# web component: slot vs attribute when passing data that is to be displayed

Tags: javascript, html, shadow-dom, custom-element

What is the better way to pass data, which purpose is to be displayed in a Shadow DOM, to a custom element. Is this by using an attribute or a slot?

**Attribute example**

```js
class MyAttributeComponent extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.attachShadow({
      mode: "open"
    });
  }

  connectedCallback() {
    const heading = this.getAttribute("heading");

    this.shadowRoot.innerHTML = `
            <h2>${heading}</h2>
          `;
  }
}
customElements.define("my-attribute-component", MyAttributeComponent);
```

```html
<my-attribute-component heading="this is my attribute heading"></my-attribute-component>
```

**Slot example**

```js
class MySlotComponent extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.attachShadow({
      mode: "open"
    });

    this.shadowRoot.innerHTML = `
            <slot></slot>
          `;
  }
}
customElements.define("my-slot-component", MySlotComponent);
```

```html
<my-slot-component>
  <h2>this is my slotted heading</h2>
</my-slot-component>
```

Comment: You should use attributes to _configure_ your component, and `<slot>` to pass in content. Attributes are good for defining behaviour that is universal, and shouldn't be used for actual content - even if it's just that that data is invisible when web components aren't rendered or javascript isn't enabled. So any actual content should be slotted. But that's an opinion, I guess.

Comment: Web Components _without_ shadowDOM can not use ``<slot>``

Answer (score 1):

There is **no** *"better"* They both do different things.

- HTML you **inject** in shadowDOM is styled by styles ***in*** shadowDOM
- **slotted** content is styled by its *container* (`<style>` in main DOM below)
  or slotted "skin" with `::slotted`

  For long read see: [::slotted CSS selector for nested children in shadowDOM slot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61626493/slotted-css-selector-for-nested-children-in-shadowdom-slot/61631668#61631668)

```js
customElements.define("my-component", class extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super()
      .attachShadow({mode:"open"})
      .innerHTML =  `<style>` +
                      `h1 { border: 5px solid blue } `+
                      `*::slotted(h1){ background:pink }`+
                    `</style>` +
                    `<slot name="title"></slot>` +
                    `<h1></h1>`;
  }
  connectedCallback() {
    this.shadowRoot.querySelector("h1").innerHTML = this.getAttribute("subtitle");
  }
});
```

```html
<style>
  h1 {
    border: 5px solid green; /* doesn't 'bleed' into shadowDOM */
    font-family: Arial;
    color: red;
  }
</style>
<my-component subtitle="Web Component World!">
  <h1 slot="title">Hello,</h1>
</my-component>
```

Comment: When displaying text within a Shadow DOM I presume that you would "most likely" want to use the `font-family` declared in the document. Otherwise you need to deal with fonts from each consumer. 


In the example you gave the h1 passed in the slot has a different font than the one declared within the Shadow DOM.

Comment: If you want that you can explicitly tell it to `inherit` the font from the host element, which gets it from the page. In this case it's because `<h1>` user agent stylesheets overwrite the parents styles. But if it was a span, it would inherit the font by default. That's more of a problem with that specific tag.

Comment: Yes, Rogier, its a contrived example. Point was to show the difference between ``<slot>`` and setting ``innerHTML``.  `font-family` is a inheritable style: https://lamplightdev.com/blog/2019/03/26/why-is-my-web-component-inheriting-styles/

Comment: I have a feeling that passing data through attributes which need to be displayed on the webpage is a bad idea. When this is done you lose the declarative nature of html. I haven’t found a case where the attribute solution made more sense.

Comment: ... no shadowdom,  no slot