# How to use Shadow Dom with Javascript and CSS modules

Tags: javascript, css, dom, es6-modules, shadow-dom

**EDIT 1**

Thanks very much @Danny for the very useful answer. I guess my question has more to do with CSS sope and encapsulation. If I import a CSS StyleSheet into a module then I don't want that Stylesheet to bleed out into the parent and lightDOM of the caller. The effect I want to achieve is similar to this basic [Custom Element](https://github.com/RichardMaher/CustElements/blob/main/slider.js) In this case I build a STYLE element and attach it to the Extension class of HTMLElement.

I'm trying to achieve the same thing with Javascript/CSS modules. I will try with myDiv.part='shadowTree' but that seems to be defeating the whole purpose of ShadowDOM.

I'll go read up om SLOTs again but I only want to expose certain elements from my module call. This is what I thought #returnedDiv::part(styleableRuleException) wass, the rest of the CSS I expected to be forcably scoped to my JS module?

WRT [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ShadowRoot/adoptedStyleSheets) I think my problem is my imported StyleSheet is not a "constructed stylesheet"? Like:-

```
 let sheet = new CSSStyleSheet();
```

But [Web.Dev](https://web.dev/articles/css-module-scripts) says ok?

**<EDIT 1**

I am trying to use Shadow DOM in my Javascript module and also import a CSS module/sheet into the Javascript module: -

**module.js**

```
import sheet from '/styles.css' assert {type: 'css'};

export function message()
{
    const myDiv = document.createElement("div");
    const shadowRoot = myDiv.attachShadow({mode:"open"});
    document.adoptedStyleSheets = [sheet];
    myDiv.textContent = "This is Text";
    return myDiv;
}
```

As soon as I add the line to .attachShadow() the content of the DIV "This is Text" stopped appearing.

If I went further an tried to adoptStyleSheets to the shadowRoot instead of the document then no CSS from styles.css took effect.

**styles.css**

```
host:: {
    background-color: yellow;
}
div {
    background-color: red;
}
```

What do I have to do to be able to use Shadow DOM in my Modules in concert with Adopted Styles from CSS modules?

**test_mod.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style type="text/css">
div div {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: lightblue;
}
</style>
<script type="module">
import {message} from "http://localhost/message.js";

document.getElementById("demo").appendChild(message());

</script>
<body>
<h1>JavaScript Modules</h1>

<div id="demo"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *As soon as I add the line to .attachShadow() the content of the DIV "This is Text" stopped appearing.*

Because you set content in **lightDOM** which will only be shown in **shadowDOM** when you `<slot>` it.

> *If I went further an tried to adoptStyleSheets to the shadowRoot instead of the document then no CSS from styles.css took effect.*

The syntax is `:host` not `host::`

Do read:

- https://web.dev/articles/constructable-stylesheets
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet

Here is a playground with almost all shadowDOM goodies.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/WebComponents/bj4n1L0r/

```html
<h1>shadowDOM, loathed but loaded</h1>
<script>
  function adoptSheet(atRoot, styles) {
    let sheet = new CSSStyleSheet();
    sheet.replaceSync(styles);
    atRoot.adoptedStyleSheets.push(sheet);
  }
  // Global CSS
  adoptSheet(document, "h1 { background: hotpink }" +
                       "div { background: pink }" +
                       "div::part(shadowH1) { background: lightgreen }");

  const myDiv = document.createElement("div");
  myDiv.setAttribute("border", "true");
  const shadowRoot = myDiv.attachShadow({ mode: "open" });
  adoptSheet(shadowRoot, ":host { background: red; padding: 5px }" +
                         ":host([border]) { border:2px dashed green }" +
                         "h1 { color: green }" +
                         "::slotted(h1) { color: blue }");

  myDiv.innerHTML =      "<h1                >I am in lightDOM</h1>";
  shadowRoot.innerHTML = "<h1 part='shadowH1'>I am in shadowDOM</h1>" +
                         "<slot>lightDOM will be slotted here</slot>";

  document.body.append(myDiv);
</script>
```

#### Notes

- Global CSS styles BOTH `<h1>` in the main document `background:hotpink`, because slotted content is not moved to shadowDOM but **reflected** to shadowDOM
  See (long read): [::slotted CSS selector for nested children in shadowDOM slot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61626493/slotted-css-selector-for-nested-children-in-shadowdom-slot/61631668#61631668)
- `::part` in global CSS can style content inside shadowDOM
  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::part
- `:host` has no Specificity, so the shadowDOM is not `background: red`
  This is so (web) Component users can override default styling (see `background:pink`), if you do not want that, add an extra `<div>` layer in your shadowDOM and style that.
- There are 2 types of (Web Component) Developers:
  Those who [moan about shadowDOM](https://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2023/11/01/blinded-by-the-light-dom/), and those who learned to master shadowDOM

  [image]

Comment: Thaks! Why do I need to use SLOTs if it's not a web component?

Comment: Because ``<slot>`` is a shadowDOM feature, not a Web Component feature. _Strictly_ speaking we call Elements created with the ``Custom Elements API`` a **Custom Element** and when you _**add**_ ``shadowDOM`` they are called **Web Components**. Everyone uses the two terms interchangeably.

Comment: Your code proves you can do without that ``Custom Elements API``. There is no _strict_ term for this. Its a native Element with shadowDOM. Note that all ``<input>, <textarea> etc.`` have ``(user-agent) shadowRoot`` built this way **by the Browser vendors**, Us mortal developers can not access those ``shadowDOM``. So shadowDOM has been around for about 12 years now.

Answer (score 0):

I've marked Danny's answer as correct because it contains heaps of useful info.

In truth mine was a schoolboy error in continuing to append child elements to the host and not the shadow root.

BTW. Didn't think anyone here would be old enough to remember Kung Fu :-)

Comment: child of the 60s, David was cool, but [Marcia Brady](https://www.google.com/search?q=marcia+brady) was my favorite.