# Declarative Shadow DOM to encapsulate

Tags: html, css, shadow-dom

I am trying to use [Declarative Shadow DOM](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/css-ui/declarative-shadow-dom) to encapsulate a header on a web-page.

```html
    <host-element>
        <template shadowrootmode="open">
            <style>
                .button {
                    background-color: green;
                }
            </style>
            <slot></slot>
        </template>
        <div>
            <div class="button">Button one</div>
            <div class="button">Button two</div>
        </div>
    </host-element>
```

In the code above I would expect the two buttons to be green, but that is not the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*slotted* **lightDOM** content is **NOT MOVED to shadowDOM**

Thus you can not style **lightDOM** FROM a **shadowDOM** `<style>`

One exception:
`::slotted` can **only** style your **outer** DIV (also known as the "lightDOM ***skin***")
See dashed blue in snippet below

You style **lightDOM** from the *container* it is in. In this case *global* DOM

[image]

very long answer: [::slotted CSS selector for nested children in shadowDOM slot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61626493/slotted-css-selector-for-nested-children-in-shadowdom-slot/61631668#61631668)

```html
<style>
 .button {
   margin: 1em;
   background: lightgreen;
 }
</style>
<host-element>
        <template shadowrootmode="open">
            <style>
                ::slotted(div) {
                  margin: 1em;
                  border: 2px dashed blue;
                }
            </style>
            <slot></slot>
        </template>
        <div>
            <div class="button">Button one</div>
            <div class="button">Button two</div>
        </div>
</host-element>
```

Comment: So my idea of taking some existing js, css and html and adding it to a shadow root, is not possible?

Comment: Its just HTML5, everything is possible, you just have to put things in the right place and order. No different than using Arrays where the _first_ element is at index 0 and not at index 1. And Tools like Lit don't help, you will learn a Tool, not the Technology. You use a Tool once you mastered the Technology. And yes, learning Web Components takes time, blood, sweat and tears.