Is it possible to slot the style of a shadowRoot?
I'm experimenting with Vanilla custom elements and it doesn't seem possible to slot a style tag:


class MyElement extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.attachShadow({mode: "open"});
  }
  connectedCallback() {
    this.shadowRoot.append(document.getElementById('my-element-template').content.cloneNode(true));
  }
}
window.customElements.define("my-element", MyElement);
<template id="my-element-template">
  <slot name="my-style">
    <style>
      p { color: red; }
    </style>
  </slot>
  <p>Why am I still red instead of green?</p>
</template>

<my-element>
  <style slot="my-style">
    p { color: green; }
  </style>
</my-element>




Note: The reason why slotting <style> does not work is because content is not moved to <slot> but reflected to <slot>. Long read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61626493/slotted-css-selector-for-nested-children-in-shadowdom-slot/61631668#61631668 adoptedStyleSheets links CSS content

Update - Move style elements to ShadowDOM
The original solution worked, but commenters suggested improvements. Style elements within a slot behave differently from other types elements. They appear in the DOM rather than the component's ShadowDOM. This is why OP's code did not work as expected. The original solution fixed this using shadowRoot.adoptedStyleSheets, but these steps were unnecessary. The simpler solution is to move the style elements directly into the ShadowDOM.
Importantly, this only applies to styles added to slots and not to styles in the component definition.


class MyElement extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.attachShadow({ mode: "open" })
  }
  connectedCallback() {
    const root = this.shadowRoot
    root.append(
      document.getElementById("my-element-template").content.cloneNode(true),
    )

    // a fix specific to OP's code
    root.querySelector("slot[name=my-style]")
      .assignedElements()
      .forEach((el) => root.append(el))

    // and a longer but more universal alternative
    // this.importStyles();
  }


  // A method to import css from any or all slots

  /**
   * Imports slot style elements from lightDOM to shadowDOM
   * @param {string} [slotname] A slot name or omit for all slots
   */
  importStyles(slotname) {
    slotname = slotname ? `slot[name="${slotname}"]` : "slot"
    const root = this.shadowRoot

    root.querySelectorAll(slotname).forEach((slot) => {
      slot.assignedElements().forEach((el) => {
        if (el instanceof HTMLStyleElement) {
          root.append(el)
        } else {
          el.querySelectorAll("style").forEach((style) => root.append(style))
        }
      })
    })
  }
}
window.customElements.define("my-element", MyElement)
p { 
  font-weight: bold;
  color: orange;
}
<p>This text is outside the component (global css)</p>

<template id="my-element-template">
  <div>
  <slot name="my-style">
    <style>
      p { color: red; }
    </style>
  </slot>
  </div>
    <p>
      This text is <i>inside</i> the component (component css)
    </p>
</template>

<my-element>
  <style slot="my-style">
    p { color: green; } 
    p:hover { color: blue; }
    p i { color: black; } 
  </style>
</my-element>



Original Solution - works, but verbose


class MyElement extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.attachShadow({mode: "open"});
  }
  connectedCallback() {
    const root = this.shadowRoot;
    root.append(document.getElementById('my-element-template').content.cloneNode(true));

    // get the slot style element
    const node = root.querySelector('slot[name=my-style]')
    .assignedNodes()[0];

    // extract the css and adopt custom style
    if (node instanceof HTMLStyleElement) {
      const stylesheet = new CSSStyleSheet();
      stylesheet.replace( node.textContent );
      root.adoptedStyleSheets = [stylesheet];
      node.remove();
    }
    
  }
}
window.customElements.define("my-element", MyElement);
p { 
  font-weight: bold;
  color: orange;
}
<p>This text is outside the component (global css)</p>

<template id="my-element-template">
  <slot name="my-style">
    <style>
      p { color: red; }
    </style>
  </slot>
    <p>
      This text is <i>inside</i> the component (component css)
    </p>
</template>

<my-element>
  <style slot="my-style">
    p { color: green; } 
    p:hover { color: blue; }
    p i { color: black; } 
  </style>
</my-element>




Thank you for showing those examples. So the <style slot="my-style"> slot is processed but doesn't replace the existing one, and doesn't work because it isn't prefixed with ::part(). Then if we want to replace all the CSS of the shadow root then we need to wipe out the existing styles and append the slotted ones manually?

Add a <p>Hello World</p> to this HTML; it will be styled green because adoptedStyleSheets do not move, they are linked. Moving a <style> from lightDOM to shadowDOM is:this.shadowRoot.append(...this.querySelectorAll("style")). Instead is still red because there are now 2 <style> "in" the <slot> The default (color:red) content (which is in shadowDOM thus styles shadowDOM) and the slotted style (which does not style shadowDOM, it is still in lightDOM (styling the whole document, thus Hello World green) and only styles shadowDOM after it is linked as adoptedStyleSheet

I overlooked something: the p i { color:red } is a higher specificity than p { color:red }, so that red is applied. The <i> is not still colored red; but again colored red. Here is a JSFiddle  to play with: https://jsfiddle.net/WebComponents/em3bva29/

Note your update still is verbose: load CSS from lightDOM -> create a new StyleSheet -> add CSS to it -> add new StyleSheet to shadowDOM That whole adoptedstylesheet is verbose because you do not use its link magical powers. Might as well do: Move 