# Does loading a font using @import inside a web component with shadow reload the file?

Tags: javascript, web-component, shadow-dom, stenciljs, stencil-component

I'm using Stencil to create a native browser web component using shadow for view encapsulation.

If at the top of my SCSS file I use

```
@import url($url-icons);
```

Will that have each component redownload the font/icon files for each component instance, there-by having a negative effect on performance?

If so, what's the best practice to handle this sort of shared dependency?

Comment: Every browser has a cache for the downloaded files. It won't download the same file twice.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to apply common CSS styles to many Shadow Roots at once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40973471/how-to-apply-common-css-styles-to-many-shadow-roots-at-once)

Answer (score 0):

The browser has a cache mechanism for those font files, so files "should" be downloaded only once (that's not the case when devtools are open with `disable cache`, which many developers use). But this is actually an implementation detail of the browser, and not of web components.

This means that importing the font itself inside a web component will cause multiple requests by the browser, and by that potentially have an extra cost - delegating the responsibility of fetching the font only once to the browser.

It's better to only include the `font-family` definition inside the web component css, and import the fonts (only) once in the app requiring the web components library or in the library init method (In `Stencil` you can add it to your `defineCustomElements()` call)